# How to find out if my app has "usage access" on Android Lollipop?

Tags: android

Android Lollipop has provided the `UsageStatsManager` service which allows apps to get information about device usage statistics, as long as the user of the device has granted the required permission through the `Settings`.

Is it possible to find out programmatically if the user has granted us the permission?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215013/check-if-my-application-has-usage-access-enabled But this works only for Nexus devices. Does not work in LG , HTC .

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the size of the list returned from UsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats. 
If the user has not granted permission, the list will be empty.

Comment: This is what we're doing right now, but I was expecting a better API to be honest...