# ActivityNotFoundException in Lollipop when trying to launch activity with intent android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, usage-statistics, activitynotfoundexception

I am trying to get the permission to access app usage data using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS) permission. THis is only being done for Lollipop and when I start activity with this intent (android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS), the app crashes (stacktrace below)

Observed that another developer noticed this issue in LG G3 phone - [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874224/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent).From user logs, I have mostly seen this occur on LG G3 and once on Samsung S5 also.

What is the right intent to launch the window for LG & Samsung S3 phone to get app usage data?

Does someone have either of these phones and can advice if this "Apps using Usage Data" permission option even exists

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle   Intent { act=android.settings.USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS }
at     android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1801)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1499)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3913)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3860)
at     android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivi    ty.java:849)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:880)
at     com.mavdev.focusoutfacebook.fragments.addablock.apps.Fragment_appsselect_addbloc    k$2.onClick(Fragment_appsselect_addblock.java:182)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5162)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20873)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

**Here is my Manifest file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="hidden"
android:installLocation="internalOnly"
android:versionCode="50"
android:versionName="2.0.5" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>    

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyActionBarTheme"
    android:vmSafeMode="true" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</application>

</manifest>
```

I dont have a real LG device (or even Samsung S3) with Lollipop on it to test. I am only testing in the Genymotion Emulator with Android 5.0 (API21) and it works fine.

Comment: Please paste your Manifest.

Comment: Just added the manifest file. I have removed the activities and receivers under the application tab - rest all is there.

Comment: I did add the following permission: "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS" />"

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296633/android-usage-access-for-android-5-samsung-devices ?

Comment: Folks, it appears this entire library is missing or hidden in the builds of Android 5 shipped by LG and Samsung. Long live fragmentation. It works fine on the Moto X build of 5, and the build on Nexus devices.

Comment: Note: Samsung's OTA update for S4 *does* have the feature. So far it is anecdotally noted to be absent in the LG G3 and Samsung S5.

Comment: The issue also occurs on the LG G Flex 2. The usage stats screen is nowhere to be seen on the any of the settings screens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.USAGE\_ACCESS\_SETTINGS }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874224/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent)

Comment: Voting to close this as duplicate since the other question is slightly older and has a correct accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Does someone know how to **listen** to changes in that setting, with code similar or analogous to

```
Context context = configuration.getContext();
ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
resolver.registerContentObserver(Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, observer = new TimeoutSettingContentObserver(context, new Handler()));
```

Here is the code:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager(); 
final ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0); 
appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE); 
appOpsManager.startWatchingMode(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAG‌​E_STATS, 
        applicationInfo.packageName,
        new AppOpsManager.OnOpChangedListener(){ 
            @Override public void onOpChanged(String op, String packageName) {
                int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(op, applicationInfo.uid, packageName); 
                boolean enabled = mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED; 
            } 
        });
```

Comment: @SunilChaudhary, usage stats was only introduced in Lollipop (21).

Answer (score 0):

I checked the same code on google nexus 5.0 and emulator , it works fine .It didnot show any error .Intent works fine and  Apps usage acess actvity is also launched though it didnot list any apps under this .

Under settings -->security --> APPS usage --  first check your device list any apps .

Try the below code and check whether your application has usage acess enable

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);


try {
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
AppOpsManager appOpsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
int mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName);
return (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
return false;
}
```

And also you can refer to this link [this link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/appusagestatistics/AppUsageStatisticsFragment.java)

Answer (score -5):

you need add activity to manifest xml like that

(under application)

```
<activity
       android:name="com.yournamespace.yourclassname"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >           
</activity>
```

Comment: I have my activities and receivers already added under application tag. I did not show it here (as I mention in my question also) for privacy reasons.

Comment: In any case, <activity> must be inside, not under, <application>