# How to check Grants Permissions at Run-Time?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

In **Android M (Preview)** the user can choose a specific app and retreive specific permission.

So I am asking *How to check Grants Permissions at Run-Time*?

Comment: I tried to built a simple demo for this https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/AndroidMRuntimePermissionDemo

Comment: I have created library for it. It is easy to use by simple steps. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/Ask-Permission

Comment: it have created a small documentation regarding the steps for requesting permissions runtime in android at http://codesfor.in/android-request-permission-dynamically-example/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use the following code copied from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+blame/71c2c37554ae53dffdf8e210f484d92af30620fa/docs/html/preview/features/runtime-permissions.jd?pli=1#548 —

> #### Request permissions if necessary
>
> ```
> if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
>             != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>         requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
>                 MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
>     
>         // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
>         // app-defined int constant
>     
>         return;
>     }
> ```
>
> #### Handle the permissions request response
>
> ```
> @Override public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
>         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
>             if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>
>                 // permission was granted, yay! do the
>                 // calendar task you need to do.
>
>             } else {
>
>                 // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                 // functionality that depends on this permission.
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // other 'switch' lines to check for other
>         // permissions this app might request
>     } }
> ```

Comment: Please bear in mind **we must have noHistory=false** in order to receive callback. Also refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33080682/1911652) in case if you don't receive callback. I wasted hours to figure it out.

Comment: I have created library for it. It is easy to use by simple steps. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/Ask-Permission

Answer (score 42):

Try this instead simple request code
https://www.learn2crack.com/2015/10/android-marshmallow-permissions.html

```
public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;

private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int camera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    int storage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int loc = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    int loc2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (camera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
    if (storage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (loc2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (loc != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty())
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,listPermissionsNeeded.toArray
                (new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: great response.

Comment: I have created library for it. It is easy to use by simple steps. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/Ask-Permission

Comment: Works perfect !

Comment: I tried this sample but it always saying security exception

Comment: @Vishali Did you add the permissions in manifest also ? once check it correct it will work

Answer (score 9):

Try this for Check Run-Time Permission:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    checkRunTimePermission();
}
```

Check run time permission:

```
private void checkRunTimePermission() {
    String[] permissionArrays = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(permissionArrays, 11111);
    } else {
         // if already permition granted
        // PUT YOUR ACTION (Like Open cemara etc..)
    }
}
```

Handle Permission result:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    boolean openActivityOnce = true;
    boolean openDialogOnce = true;
    if (requestCode == 11111) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];

            isPermitted = grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // user rejected the permission
                boolean showRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission);
                if (!showRationale) {
                    //execute when 'never Ask Again' tick and permission dialog not show
                } else {
                    if (openDialogOnce) {
                        alertView();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (isPermitted)
            if (isPermissionFromGallery)
                openGalleryFragment();
    }
}
```

Set custom alert:

```
private void alertView() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);

    dialog.setTitle("Permission Denied")
            .setInverseBackgroundForced(true)
            //.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_black_24dp)
            .setMessage("Without those permission the app is unable to save your profile. App needs to save profile image in your external storage and also need to get profile image from camera or external storage.Are you sure you want to deny this permission?")

            .setNegativeButton("I'M SURE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                    dialoginterface.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("RE-TRY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                    dialoginterface.dismiss();
                    checkRunTimePermission();

                }
            }).show();
}
```

Comment: isPermitted?? where its assigned

Answer (score 6):

use [Dexter library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)

Include the library in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
}
```

this example requests `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.`

```
Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        // permission is granted, open the camera
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        // check for permanent denial of permission
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // navigate user to app settings
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
```

check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49201404/9130109)

Answer (score 3):

```
fun hasPermission(permission: String): Boolean {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) return true // must be granted after installed.
      return mAppSet.appContext.checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also query by following code snippet as backward compatible;

```
int hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS);
if (hasPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Do smthng
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Location runtime Permission

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("yes","yes");

            } else {
                Log.d("yes","no");
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

original (not mine) post  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28921136/how-to-check-if-android-permission-package-usage-stats-permission-is-given)

For special permissions, such as `android.Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` used  `AppOpsManager`: 
**Kotlin**

```
private fun hasPermission(permission:String, permissionAppOpsManager:String): Boolean {
    var granted = false
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // requires kitkat
        val appOps = applicationContext!!.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager

        // requires lollipop
        val mode = appOps.checkOpNoThrow(permissionAppOpsManager,
                              android.os.Process.myUid(), applicationContext!!.packageName)

        if (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_DEFAULT) {
            granted = applicationContext!!.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        } else {
            granted = mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
        }
    }

    return granted
}
```

and anywhere in code:

```
val permissionAppOpsManager = AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS
val permission = android.Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS
val permissionActivity = Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS

if (hasPermission(permission, permissionAppOpsManager)) {
    Timber.i("has permission: $permission")
    // do here what needs permission
} else {
    Timber.e("has no permission: $permission")
    // start activity to get permission
    startActivity(Intent(permissionActivity))
}
```

Other permissions you can get with [TedPermission library](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedPermission)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below library in git :

[RuntimePermission](https://github.com/manoj140220/RuntimePermission)

Implementation :

```
        allprojects {
            repositories {
                ...
                maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            }
        }
        
        dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.manoj140220:RuntimePermission:1.0.3'
        }
    
    
      
    
        new RuntimePermission({Current Class Object}, String[] , {ActvityContext});
          
          String[] : permission array.
          example  : String[] permissionArray = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS,...} 
    
    Implement : {PermissionNotify}
    
    interface notifier methods.
    
    @Override
    public void notifyPermissionGrant() {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void notifyPermissionDeny() {
         
    }
```