# Android M Permissions: onRequestPermissionsResult() not being called

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

I'm updating our app to use the new M runtime permissions system.
It's all working except for onRequestPermissionsResult(). I need to check a permission on a button press, and if it's successful, send a text message. When I grant permission to do it, the dialog closes, but it doesn't trigger the Send Text until I press the button again.

I've debugged and set breakpoints in the onRequestPermissionsResult() method but it never goes into it.

This method gets called first:

```
    private void askForPermission() {
    String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permissions, PERMISSIONS_CODE);
}
```

And then my callback looks like this:

```
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_CODE) {
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            String permission = permissions[i];
            int grantResult = grantResults[i];

            if (permission.equals(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    onPPSButtonPress();
                } else {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, PERMISSIONS_CODE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has anybody run into a similar issue?
Appreciate any help with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue was actually being caused by NestedFragments.
Basically most fragments we have extend a HostedFragment which in turn extends a CompatFragment. Having these nested fragments caused issues which eventually were solved by another developer on the project.

He was doing some low level stuff like bit switching to get this working so I'm not too sure of the actual final solution

Comment: This helped me solve my issue: I had to redirect the onRequestPermissionsResult from the parent fragment to the child (nested) fragment. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 589):

I ran into the same issue and I just found the solution. When using the Support library, you have to use the correct method calls. For example:

- When in **AppCompatActivity**, you should use **ActivityCompat.requestPermissions**;
- When in **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**, you should use simply **requestPermissions** (this is an instance method of android.support.v4.app.Fragment)

If you call ActivityCompat.requestPermissions in a fragment, the **onRequestPermissionsResult** callback is called on the activity and not the fragment.

Comment: It also occurs with noHistory activities:
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2915

Comment: "When in android.support.v4.app.Fragment, you should use simply requestPermissions " - thank you!

Comment: What if I have a support fragment in AppCompatActivity?

Comment: @AnthonyBobenrieth so what is the solution here for noHistory activites? We simply can't request permissions from them?

Comment: The link is broken @AnthonyBobenrieth. Is there any solution for no history?

Comment: When using `Fragment.requestPermissions()`, the parent Activity is actually receiving the `onRequestPermissionsResult()`. (This is with support library 23.3.0)

Comment: Actually this is the answer... `FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(Fragment fragment, String[] permissions, int requestCode)`

Comment: plus one: for mentioning "callback is on the activity, not the fragment"

Comment: @yavor87 What if I want to request permission inside a `Service` ?

Comment: just stressing on the importance of calling super implementation from activity as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35245235/3061221

Comment: Don't forget to add this to your activity:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33995827/3404007

Comment: I have android.support.v4.app.Fragment and used requestPermission() but result just caame in Activity.

Comment: Wow, Android documentation mentions nothing about this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 106):

You can try this:

```
requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSIONS_CODE);
```

If you are calling this code from a fragment it has it's own requestPermissions method. I believe the problem is that you are calling static method.

Pro Tip if you want the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in a fragment:
`FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(Fragment fragment, String[] permissions, int requestCode)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did notice that there is a requestPermissions method if its in a fragment. I am in a fragment and I tried calling just requestPermissions, unfortunately it didn't work. I also tried what you mentioned and it also didn't work.

Comment: This worked for me in Android M. But just wondering if it would cause any issues in Pre-M devices?

Comment: @goodgamerguy make sure you dont use the request code in onRequestPermissionsResult of activity. if your activity also uses onRequestPermissionsResult callback you should provide default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

Answer (score 69):

I hope it works fine

For Activity :

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,permissionsList,REQUEST_CODE);
```

For Fragment :

```
 requestPermissions(permissionsList,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: What about SDK 15 and lower ?

Comment: You don't need permission about SDK 15, only Marshmallow and above version need..

Answer (score 51):

I encountered this problem too. If you want the activity that handles permissions not in the history/recents, then you will be tempted to change your `AndroidManifest.xml` entry.

If you set the activity that you call `requestPermissions` or `AppCompatActivity.requestPermissions` with

```
android:noHistory="true"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` then `onRequestPermissionsResult()` will not be called. This is true if your Activity is derived from `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`.

This can be fixed by removing both flags from 'AndroidManifest.xml' and finishing your activity with `finishAndRemoveTask()` instead.

Comment: I would have rather not had to remove the noHistory attribute, but this was the solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had the issue on Marshmallow but not on Nougat, thank you it worked for me

Answer (score 38):

If you have `onRequestPermissionsResult` in both activity and fragment, make sure to call `super.onRequestPermissionsResult` in activity. It is not required in fragment, but it is in activity.

Comment: Also, note that if you target an API (such as 19 for example), you will still be under the old permission model system, and thus, do not receive the request permission related function calls

Comment: see my answer if you have extended another activity that does not call super

Comment: Stumbled upon this one. `FragmentActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(..)` is where the call to fragment's `onRequestPermissionsResult(..)` is forwarded to.

Comment: @Bonatti So if i try to request a permission in android 4.4.2 i won't get a result? Thus I cannot change the permissions , only see them?

Comment: @AlexanderFragotsis You will get a result. Only difference is you wont be asked to grant permission, instead you will be automatically granted by the system.

Comment: Wow, there something inconsistent here. I have two apps. One requires that and the other not.

Answer (score 32):

Answer deprecated please refer to : 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Inside fragment, you need to call:

```
FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(permissionsList, RequestCode)
```

Not:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity, permissionsList, RequestCode);
```

Comment: Relates to android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat

Comment: FragmentCompat is deprecated as of API 27.1.0.

Comment: my answer is deprecated please refer to : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 15):

If you are using requestPermissions in fragment, it accepts 2 parameters instead of 3.

You should use `requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSIONS_CODE);`

Comment: Actually it does provide an answer to the question. Calling requestPermissions (instance method of fragment) instead of ActivityCompat.requestPermissions, the result method is triggered. Which is the main issue here. Thank you Don

Answer (score 15):

If for some reason you have extended a custom Activity located in some external library that do not call the super you will need to manually call the Fragment super.onRequestPermissionsResult yourself in your Activity onRequestPermissionsResult.

```
YourActivity extends SomeActivityNotCallingSuperOnRequestPermissionsResult{
Fragment requestingFragment;//the fragment requesting the permission
...
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestingFragment!=null)
            requestingFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
...
```

Comment: i have normal activity which extends `AppCompatActivity`,Should I still use `super()`?

Answer (score 12):

You have the *checkPermissions* function for pre Marshmallow devices in *FragmentCompat*.
I use like this:

```
FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
```

Comment: This is only working if the permission is asked inside android.app.fragment, and you have to import support-v13 library!

Comment: FragmentCompat.requestPermissions() doesn't work with android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Anyone know how to handle this.

Answer (score 12):

I have found out that is important where you call `android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requestPermissions`.

If you do it in `onCreate()`, `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is never called.

Solution: Call it in `onActivityCreated()`;

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) 
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 0);

}
```

Comment: I'm facing same problem but I'm not able to get `onActivityCreated()` in my code. SDK 23.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated%28android.os.Bundle%29, or see sample at http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/android-fragment-example.html

Comment: I'm not in fragment, I'm trying to do it on onCreate of an activity

Comment: Hmm, or use `onPause()`?

Answer (score 9):

```
 /* use the object of your fragment to call the 
 * onRequestPermissionsResult in fragment after
 * in activity and use different request Code for 
 * both Activity and Fragment */

   if (isFragment)
    mFragment.requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new
    String[permissions.size()]),requestPermission);

   else
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity,permissions.toArray(new
    String[permissions.size()]),requestPermission);
```

Answer (score 6):

This will work..

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Comment: the super implementation calls the fragments implementation not hte framework

Answer (score 5):

If you are calling this code from a fragment it has it’s own requestPermissions method.

So basic concept is, If you are in an Activity, then call

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            permissionsList,
                            permissionscode);
```

and if in a Fragment, just call

```
requestPermissions(permissionsList,
                            permissionscode);
```

Comment: Requires API level 23... On earlier ones use `FragmentCompat.requestPermissions()`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem except I was pressing a button to make a call, which triggers the callIntent. I checked permission first, if not granted I ask for permission and onRequestPermissionResult I call the check permission and call again.

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constants.PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE: {
            if ( grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                checkPermissionsAndCall();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void checkPermissionsAndCall(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(),
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions( new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, Constants.PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
        }
        else{
            callIntent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [goodgamerguy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33081173/8417594) the solution is:

```
myFragment.this.requestPermissions(....)
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you check everything according to above answers, make sure your request code is not 0!!!

check the code of onRequestPermissionsResult() in FragmentActivity.java:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    int index = (requestCode>>16)&0xffff;
    if (index != 0) {
        index--;

        String who = mPendingFragmentActivityResults.get(index);
        mPendingFragmentActivityResults.remove(index);
        if (who == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Activity result delivered for unknown Fragment.");
            return;
        }
        Fragment frag = mFragments.findFragmentByWho(who);
        if (frag == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Activity result no fragment exists for who: " + who);
        } else {
            frag.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode&0xffff, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void showContacts() {
    if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    } else {
        doShowContacts();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        doShowContacts();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an amazing solution to achieve this make a BaseActivity like this.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(this));


}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                CustomToast.getInstance().setCustomToast("Now you can share the Hack.");

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now yo can call the code to ask for permission like this

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
```

Now every time this happens anywhere whether in your fragment or in any activity the base activity would be called.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_CODE);`. Do not use FragmentCompat if you are using v4.

Comment: Please elaborate why.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** saw someone else's answer about calling `super.onRequestPermissionResult()` in Activity and that fixes the request code issue I mentioned and calls the **fragment's onRequestPermissionResult.**

*ignore this stuff:*

For me it was calling the `onRequestPermissionResult` of the Activity despite me calling `fragment.requestPermission(...)`, BUT it returned the result with an incorrect requestCode (111 turned into 65647 why ??? I'll never know).

Luckily this is the only permission we request on that screen so I just ignore the request code (don't have time to figure out why it's not correct right now)

Comment: Add 65536 and 111 and you will get it. This is because of bit masks. See some topics.

Answer (score 1):

### Details

- Kotlin 1.2.70
- checked in minSdkVersion 19
- Android studio 3.1.4

### Algorithm

**module** - camera, location, ....

1. Check if hasSystemFeature (if **module** exist in phone)
2. Check if user has access to **module**
3. Send permissions request (ask user to allow **module** usage)

### Features

1. Work with Activities and Fragments
2. Has only one result response
3. Can check several **modules** in one request

### Solution

```
class PermissionType(val manifest_permission: String, val packageManager: String) {
    object Defined {
        val camera = PermissionType(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)
        val currentLocation = PermissionType(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS)
    }
}

class  Permission {

    enum class PermissionResult {
        ACCESS_ALLOWED, ACCESS_DENIED, NO_SYSTEM_FEATURE;
    }

    interface ManagerDelegate {
        fun permissionManagerDelegate(result: Array<Pair<String, PermissionResult>>)
    }

    class Manager internal constructor(private val delegate: ManagerDelegate?) {

        private var context: Context? = null
        private var fragment: Fragment? = null
        private var activity: AppCompatActivity? = null
        private var permissionTypes: Array<PermissionType> = arrayOf()
        private val REQUEST_CODE = 999
        private val semaphore = Semaphore(1, true)
        private var result: Array<Pair<String, PermissionResult>> = arrayOf()


        constructor(permissionType: PermissionType, delegate: ManagerDelegate?): this(delegate) {
            permissionTypes = arrayOf(permissionType)
        }

        constructor(permissionTypes: Array<PermissionType>, delegate: ManagerDelegate?): this(delegate) {
            this.permissionTypes = permissionTypes
        }

        init {
            when (delegate) {
                is Fragment -> {
                    this.fragment = delegate
                    this.context = delegate.context
                }

                is AppCompatActivity -> {
                    this.activity = delegate
                    this.context = delegate
                }
            }
        }

        private fun hasSystemFeature(permissionType: PermissionType) : Boolean {
            return context?.packageManager?.hasSystemFeature(permissionType.packageManager) ?: false
        }

        private fun hasAccess(permissionType: PermissionType) : Boolean {
            return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) true else {
                context?.checkSelfPermission(permissionType.manifest_permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            }
        }

        private fun sendRequest(permissionTypes: Array<String>) {

            if (fragment != null) {
                fragment?.requestPermissions(permissionTypes, REQUEST_CODE)
                return
            }

            if (activity != null){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity!!, permissionTypes, REQUEST_CODE)
            }
        }

        fun check() {

            semaphore.acquire()
            AsyncTask.execute {
                var permissionsForSendingRequest: Array<String> = arrayOf()
                this.result = arrayOf()

                for (it in permissionTypes) {
                    if (!hasSystemFeature(it)) {
                        result += Pair(it.manifest_permission, PermissionResult.NO_SYSTEM_FEATURE)
                        continue
                    }

                    if (hasAccess(it)) {
                        result += Pair(it.manifest_permission, PermissionResult.ACCESS_ALLOWED)
                    } else {
                        permissionsForSendingRequest += it.manifest_permission
                    }
                }

                if (permissionsForSendingRequest.isNotEmpty()) {
                    sendRequest(permissionsForSendingRequest)
                } else {
                    delegate?.permissionManagerDelegate(result)
                }
            }
        }

        fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
            when (requestCode) {
                REQUEST_CODE -> {
                    if (grantResults.isEmpty()) {
                        return
                    }
                    for ((i,permission) in permissions.withIndex()) {
                        for (item in this.permissionTypes) {
                            if (permission == item.manifest_permission && i < grantResults.size) {
                                result += if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    Pair(item.manifest_permission, PermissionResult.ACCESS_ALLOWED)
                                } else {
                                    Pair(item.manifest_permission, PermissionResult.ACCESS_DENIED)
                                }
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    delegate?.permissionManagerDelegate(result)
                }
            }
            semaphore.release()
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage in Activity (in fragment the same)

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Permission.ManagerDelegate {

    private lateinit var permissionManager: Permission.Manager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.base_activity)

        permissionManager = Permission.Manager(arrayOf(PermissionType.Defined.camera, PermissionType.Defined.currentLocation), this)
        permissionManager.check()
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        permissionManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }


    override fun permissionManagerDelegate(result: Array<Pair<String, Permission.PermissionResult>>) {
        result.forEach {
            println("!!! ${it.first} ${it.second}")
//            when (it.second) {
//                Permission.PermissionResult.NO_SYSTEM_FEATURE -> {
//                }
//
//                Permission.PermissionResult.ACCESS_DENIED  -> {
//                }
//
//                Permission.PermissionResult.ACCESS_ALLOWED -> {
//                }
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i want to show my code how i managed this.

```
public class CheckPermission {

public Context context;

public static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE =  200;

public CheckPermission(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public boolean isPermissionGranted(){
    int read_contact = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context.getApplicationContext() , READ_CONTACTS);
    int phone = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context.getApplicationContext() , CALL_PHONE);

    return read_contact == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && phone == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
   }
}
```

Here in this class i want to check permission granted or not. Is not then i will call permission from my MainActivity like

```
public void requestForPermission() {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]    {READ_CONTACTS, CALL_PHONE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    return;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Now in the onCreate method you need to call requestForPermission() function.

That's it.Also you can request multiple permission at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I also met a problem that even if you call correct requestPermissions, you still can have this problem. The issue is that parent activity may override this method without calling super. Add super and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

for kotlin users, here my extension to check and validate permissions without override onRequestPermissionResult

```
 * @param permissionToValidate (request and check currently permission)
 *
 * @return recursive boolean validation callback (no need OnRequestPermissionResult)
 *
 * */
internal fun Activity.validatePermission(
    permissionToValidate: String,
    recursiveCall: (() -> Boolean) = { false }
): Boolean {
    val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        permissionToValidate
    )

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (recursiveCall()) {
            return false
        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(permissionToValidate),
            110
        )
        return this.validatePermission(permissionToValidate) { true }
    }

    return true

}
```