# onRequestPermissionResult of the parent activity is called instead of the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I am trying to implement the new permissions model into my application. I am facing a weird issue. When I request with code i in a fragment, then onRequestPermissionResult of that fragment is not called, instead only the parent activity's onRequestPermissionResult is called with the same request code. This is causing unusual behaviour. I am using v4supportFragment. my min api is 14 and max is 23.

Note: This is not a nested fragment. Also, I have browsed this post of stackoverflow but it is not that helpful.

[Request runtime permissions from v4.Fragment and have callback go to Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890702/request-runtime-permissions-from-v4-fragment-and-have-callback-go-to-fragment)

Comment: Post some relevant code.

Comment: Here's the line of code that I am using for requesting permission .ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissionGroup, requestCode);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here's the line of code that I am using for requesting permission .ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissionGroup, requestCode);

With this call, the result will go to `activity`. The fragment is not in the parameter list, and you are not calling a method on the fragment, and so the fragment is not involved.

[Use `FragmentCompat.requestPermissions()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat.html#requestPermissions%28android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String[],%20int%29) if you want the response to go to a native `Fragment`. Or, [call `requestPermissions()` on a v4 `Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#requestPermissions%28java.lang.String[],%20int%29) to have the response go to that fragment.