# onRequestPermissionsResult not being called in fragment if defined in both fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a fragment in which I have recyclerview and setting data in this recyclerview using recyclerview adapter.

Now, I am having a button in the adapter's list item clicking on which I need to check the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in android for new permission model in android.

I have created a new function in this adapter's fragment to check if permission is granted or not and request for permission if not granted already.

I have passed MyFragment.this as a parameter in the adapter and calling the fragment's method on the button click in the adapter.

I have used the below code to call requestPermission in fragment.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
       requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                ConstantVariables.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
```

I have overridden the `onRequestPermissionsResult` method in fragment by using the below code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ConstantVariables.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, proceed to the normal flow.
                startImageUploading();
            } else {}
```

But it is not getting called, instead of this Activity's onRequestPermissionsResult method is getting called.

I have defined the same onRequestPermissionsResult method in fragment's parent activity also and it is getting called.

I can not remove the activity's onRequestPermissionsResult method but want to call fragment's onRequestPermissionsResult method when I request permission from fragment.
How can I do this? Am I doing something wrong here, please help me if anyone have idea here.

Comment: refer this link [run time permissions in fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions/38563687#38563687) This is the exact solution

Answer (score 460, accepted):

Edited answer to cover broader issues

I think you are confusing the method for fragment and activity. Had a similar issue my project last month. Please check if you have finally the following:

1. In AppCompatActivity use the method **ActivityCompat.requestpermissions**
2. In v4 support fragment you should use **requestpermissions**
3. Catch is if you call AppcompatActivity.requestpermissions in your fragment then callback will come to activity and not fragment
4. Make sure to call `super.onRequestPermissionsResult` from the activity's `onRequestPermissionsResult`.

See if it helps .

Comment: Just to double check make sure you have super.onrequestpermissionresult set in your activity

Comment: Adding `super.onrequestpermissionresult` in activity's onrequestpermissionresult call the fragment's onrequestpermissionresult when I request permission using `requestpermissions`.

This is working fine now, thank you so much.. :)

Comment: The super.onrequestpermissionresult was missing from the activity callback, leading to my fragment callback not getting called

Comment: Number 3 and 4 were my issues.

Comment: *requestPermissions()* requires API level 23. Is there another solution that is backwards compatible for API level 21?

Comment: number 2 is my issue. I use ActivityCompat.requestPermissions instead of the one from v4 fragment.

Comment: I'm using API 26 and there is stil the same bug... my dialog ask for permission but the handler is caught in my main activity.... what should I do?

Comment: @msc87 1. in onRequestPermissionsResult of activity and fragment , the first line should be : **super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);**  2.in fragment where you are recognize the permission not granted just call requestPermission method like this : **requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);**

Comment: Solved my problem. We should find this details more often in the Official documentation!

Comment: Number 4 is not actually propagates the call to fragment in the targetsdk 28. The SDK check and requestpermissions from fragment would work.

Comment: Update: If you are using Jetpack Navigation in your project, then it not required to call super.onRequestPermissionsResult from the activity's onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: Once and for all, lets admin that Google screwed this up!.

Answer (score 167):

I requested location permission from a fragment and in the fragment, I needed to change this:

```
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQ_CODE);
```

to this:

```
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQ_CODE);
```

then the onRequestPermissionsResult was called in the fragment.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: it's not working with kotlin can you please help me for the same here is used this **requestPermissions(context as Activity ,permissionList.toTypedArray(), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST)**

Comment: Thanks :),you save my time

Answer (score 42):

> This is a common mistake that people make when coding for marshmallow.
>
> When in AppCompatActivity, you should use
> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions; When in
> `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, you should use simply
> `requestPermissions (this is an instance method of android.support.v4.app.Fragment)` If you call
> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions in a fragment, the
> `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback is called on the activity and not
> the fragment.

```
requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSIONS_CODE);
```

If you are calling this code from a fragment it has it’s own requestPermissions method.

So basic concept is, If you are in an Activity, then call

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

and if in a Fragment, just call

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

For the reference, I have obtained the answer from this link https://www.coderzheaven.com/2016/10/12/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-called-on-fragments/

Answer (score 19):

change this :

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    activity,
    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS
)
```

to this :

```
requestPermissions(
     arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS),
     PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS
)
```

Comment: The lower one is for use in a fragment (onRequestPermissionsResult is called in fragment), the ActivityCompat version is for use when the onRequestPermissionsResult is sited in the Activity.

Answer (score 10):

In fragment you shouldn't use ActivityCompat for requestPermissions and you just use requestPermissions and pass two parameters in method.

1. String for permission
2. RequestCode.

for exp :

```
 requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
```

Answer (score 6):

The method `requestPermissions` on Fragments requires API level 23 or higher.
If your app targets a lower version you can use

```
FragmentCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            ConstantVariables.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

First you need to add the support-v13 dependency:

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:$supportLibVersion"
```

Comment: FragmentCompat is deprecated from version 27.1.0

Answer (score 6):

You must call the `Fragment.requestPermission()` if you want to get into the `onPermissionResult` of your Fragment.

Answer (score 3):

you can call the Fragment method below

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow
                // in your app.
                doActionBecauseNowYouCanBro();
            } else {
                // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because
                // the features requires a permission that the user has denied.
                // At the same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to
                // system settings in an effort to convince the user to change
                // their decision.
                showWhyRequestPermissionsAndDontBlockUserItsCalledManners();
            }
            return;
    }
    // Other 'case' lines to check for other
    // permissions this app might request.

}
```

Answer (score 3):

when we requestPermission from fragment the android change our requestCode in

> requestPermissionsFromFragment

This is code from FragmetActivity :

```
 void requestPermissionsFromFragment(@NonNull Fragment fragment, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode == -1) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, requestCode);
        return;
    }
    checkForValidRequestCode(requestCode);
    try {
        mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment = true;
        int requestIndex = allocateRequestIndex(fragment);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,
                ((requestIndex + 1) << 16) + (requestCode & 0xffff));
    } finally {
        mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment = false;
    }
}
```

You Can See **(requestIndex + 1) << 16) + (requestCode & 0xffff)**
and when

> onRequestPermissionsResult

android check the request code if it was send from fragment it pass the result to fragment Other wise it don't pass it to fragment
This is Code from FragmentActivity:

```
enter code here@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    mFragments.noteStateNotSaved();
    int index = (requestCode >> 16) & 0xffff;
    if (index != 0) {
        index--;

        String who = mPendingFragmentActivityResults.get(index);
        mPendingFragmentActivityResults.remove(index);
        if (who == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Activity result delivered for unknown Fragment.");
            return;
        }
        Fragment frag = mFragments.findFragmentByWho(who);
        if (frag == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Activity result no fragment exists for who: " + who);
        } else {
            frag.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode & 0xffff, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Summary

So if you call activity.requestPermission() or ActivityCompat.requestPermission it pass the result to your **Activity** And if you call fragment.requestPermission() it pass the result to your **Activity AND Fragment**

Answer (score 2):

```
private void showContacts() {
 if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
         != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
             PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_STORAGE);
 } else {
     doShowContacts();
 }
}

 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
     int[] grantResults) {
 if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_STORAGE
         && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     doShowContacts();
 }
 }
```

change permission

Comment: Hi user2002721; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: The program might throw an array out of bounds exception if you try and access index 0 of grantResults without checking the length first.  It happened to my program.  I separated the if statement for grantResults as an inner if statement to prevent that from happening, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

This accepted answer is not worked for me, so i found my own solution, explained below:

1.First i created a method, in fragment:

```
public static void MyOnRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults){
        if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission: true");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "permission: false");
        }
}
```

2.And then called it from its underlying activity:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode ==1){
        SignupFragment.MyOnRequestPermissionResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

And it is working ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Kotlin you should exectly specify that you are calling fragment method, not activity

```
 fragment.requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSIONS_CODE);
```

[Android M Permissions: onRequestPermissionsResult() not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714787/android-m-permissions-onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called/33080682#33080682)

[Request runtime permissions from v4.Fragment and have callback go to Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890702/request-runtime-permissions-from-v4-fragment-and-have-callback-go-to-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Verify that both `PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE` in`onRequestPermissionsResult` and inside your`Fragment` contains the same value.

Answer (score 0):

For the tragetSDK 28,The SDK check (>23) and requestpermissions from fragment would work. The ActivityCompat.requestPermissions is failing (if you set request code below 65536, the permission dialog would appear and if the user allows the permission, the permissions are provided, but no callback will happen. But if you set above 65536, ActivityCompat.requestPermissions will fail immediately. i don't know the reasoning behind this logic. may be a bug or intentional).

**Working code:**

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_ACCESS_REQUEST);
                    }
```

Comment: you don't need to do the version check.  in versions below 23, it'll just return the 'permission granted' value.  Developer's choice here:  avoid the 'if' block for simplicity or avoid the request call when not needed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Your fragment can be initialized from the activity layout.
Like that:

main_activty.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.exampe.SomeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This issue was solved for me when I used `FragmentTransaction` instead

Answer (score 0):

in APIs below 23 you can create an interface in the activity then implement it in the child fragment and when you get permission request result in the activity pass it to the implemented interface in fragment. 
Its this simple :)

Answer (score -5):

This issue was actually being caused by NestedFragments. Basically most fragments we have extend a HostedFragment which in turn extends a CompatFragment. Having these nested fragments caused issues which eventually were solved by another developer on the project.

He was doing some low level stuff like bit switching to get this working so I'm not too sure of the actual final solution

Comment: Instead of copying an answer, you could just provide a link - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33081173/630833