# onRequestPermissionsResult not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, runtime-permissions, android-runtime

i'm trying to implement Marshmallow's permission support, but my code inside "onRequestPermissionsResult" is never called.

When working in an Activity its working but in fragment I am facing the problem i.e, the control is not coming in onRequestPermissionsResult()

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            mCheckPermission();
                        }
```

In the mCheckPermission():-

```
public void mCheckPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION );

        }
    }
```

The dialog pops up with 2 buttons. DENY and ALLOW.
When clicking on the button the controls is not coming inside the onRequestPermissionCheck();

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode){
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //call your action

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989288/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-fragment-if-defined-in-both-fragm

Comment: I have already called requestpermissions() and I am not calling ActivityCompat.requestpermission();

Comment: 1. If you overridden the activity's `onRequestPermissionsResult` then call it's `super.onRequestPermissionsResult`. 2. Try to remove the fragment's `super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);` or just put it to the end of the function.

Answer (score 40):

Instead of using the activity version of `requestPermission`, you need to use the `support.v4.app.fragment` requestPermission.

[Fragment Request Permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html)

Change

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_CONTACT);
```

To

```
requestPermissions(new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_CONTACT);
```

and onRequestPermissionsResult will be called properly.

[Credits](https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/challenge-2-solution-onrequestpermissionsresult-was-not-called-back-on-fragment-so-used-it-in-the-activity-instead/9777)