# I am trying to check runtime permissions by calling a class inside fragment. But onRequestPermissionsResult is not working inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to check runtime permissions inside a fragment by calling permissions class but in fragment overided  method to get result of permissions granted or not is not working in fragment

Here is method of class where i check or request permissions

```
 public boolean checkPermissionForExternalStorage(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

 public void requestPermissionForExternalStorage(){
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            Toast.makeText(activity, "External Storage permission needed. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
```

Here is my Fragment

```
    package in.prsc.com.prscportal;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Bhuvan on 05-Aug-16.
 */
public class LEP extends Fragment {
    View myView;
    ProgressBar pb;
    WebView mWebView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
    public static int temp_perm;
    MarshmallowPermissions marshmallowPermissions;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE) {
                if (uploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
            // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.web_front, container, false);
        pb = (ProgressBar) myView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mWebView = (WebView) myView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

        marshmallowPermissions = new MarshmallowPermissions(getActivity());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (!marshmallowPermissions.checkPermissionForExternalStorage()) {
                marshmallowPermissions.requestPermissionForExternalStorage();
            }
        }

        return myView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MarshmallowPermissions.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   // Here i have to do my code after permissions granted


                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what's the problem you're facing??

Comment: onRequestPermissionsResult this method is not working @sumit

Comment: what do you mean by not working is it not getting called or what??

Comment: when i have to code inside this method. it didn't show result.

i think compiler is unable to call that method when user granted permission @sumit

Comment: change  marshmallowPermissions = new MarshmallowPermissions(getActivity()); to MarshMallowPermission(Context context, Fragment fragment)

Comment: issue still remains @akhilesh0707

Comment: @BhuvanArora try this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35996955/1548824

Answer (score 0):

For Fragment, We have to pass Reference in Class 
Create Constructor in `MarshmallowPermissions` Class

```
public MarshmallowPermissions(Context context, Fragment fragment) {

            Log.e(TAG, "MarshMallowPermission() called with: " + "context = [" + context + "], activity = [" + fragment + "]");
            this.fragment = fragment;
            this.context = context;
        }

public void requestPermissionForFragmentWriteExternalStorage() throws Exception {
        try {
            fragment.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

public boolean checkPermissionForWriteExternalStorage() {
            int result = context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        return false;
    }

 marshmallowPermissions = new MarshmallowPermissions(getActivity(),fragment);
```

Comment: still not working.
can u please provide me proper working example

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer
I tried and check permissions in my fragment instead of calling from other class and it works

Apply below code in oncreate of fragment

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
       checkPermissionForExternalStorage();

    }



    return myView;

}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean checkPermissionForExternalStorage(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return true;
    } else {
       requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Override below method in fragment

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("req_result", "success");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// Do your stuff here after user granted permissions
                } else {

                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
```