# onRequestPermissionsResult doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, permissions, android-permissions

I have this code that asks you for permission to take the user's location, but when the user accepts, it does not go to the function "onRequestPermissionsResult", I have checked it with the "logi", I want that when the user accepts the request, "onRequestPermissionsResult" was called of that function, thank you all!

```
public class PerdidosMapa_Fragment extends Fragment {
   // BitmapDescriptor pin = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin);

    public PerdidosMapa_Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;


    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perdidosmap, container, false);
        mMapView= (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume();

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;


                if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        //Request location updates:
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }



                markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

                googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);




                //PER CRIDAR BASE DE DADES FIREBASE PERDIDOS BASE DADES FIREBASE
                DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference perdidosUbiRef = rootRef.child("Perdidos");

                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        LatLng ubicacion;//ubicacion va canviant a mesurea recorrent base de dades
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);

                            String descripcion = ds.child("descripción").getValue(String.class);
                            Float Lat = ds.child("ubicación").child("lat").getValue(Float.class);
                            Float Long = ds.child("ubicación").child("long").getValue(Float.class);


                            ubicacion =  new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Lat)), Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Long)));//crea markers
                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(ubicacion).
                                    title(name)
                                    .snippet(descripcion)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icomap))
                            );



                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
                perdidosUbiRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);



               //AGAFA UBICACIÓ INICIAL USUARI I DIRECCIONA CAMARA
                LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                 boolean network_enabled = mgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                 Location location;


                if(network_enabled) {//si internet va
                    if (checkLocationPermission()) {
                        location = mgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);// i permis concedit et pilla ultima ubicacio


                        if (location != null) { //agafa posició de location que agafa ubicació per la xarxa no pel GPS. al carregar el mapa i posa la camara
                            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).zoom(12).build();
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition
                                    (cameraPosition));
                        }


                        mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1f, new LocationListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {//cada vegada qe es canvia ubicació crida aquesta funció

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                            }

                        });

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("")
                        .setMessage("")
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]
                                        {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        1);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i("locationPermission", "onRequestPermissionsResult: Entra a la funció ");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        Log.i("locationPermission", "onRequestPermissionsResult: Dóna localització al permetre el permis ");
                    }

                } else {



                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

And onRequestPermissionsResult method:

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i("locationPermission", "onRequestPermissionsResult: Entra a la funció ");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // location-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        Log.i("locationPermission", "onRequestPermissionsResult: Dóna localització al permetre el permis ");
                    }

                } else {



                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not a problem of android studio. 
please check this, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989288/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-fragment-if-defined-in-both-fragm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onRequestPermissionsResult not being called in fragment if defined in both fragment and activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989288/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-fragment-if-defined-in-both-fragm)

Comment: it doesn't work for me,  i've already checked, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try overriding onRequestPermissionResult in parent Activity of fragment instead of the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

In Fragments, when you request user's permission you should use `requestPermissions()` instead of `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`