# function not working inside Fragment onRequestPermissionsResult why

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    // super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    Log.wtf("here grand result" , requestCode.toString(),)
    Log.wtf("here grand result" , grantResults.toString(),)

    if(requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION){

        if(grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            getUserLocation()
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(),"Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

I am always get  the auto toast message from here but when location granted then i wants to call a function but  this override method not working inside fragment please help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989288/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-fragment-if-defined-in-both-fragm

Comment: i have already seen but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to call **onRequestPermissionResult** method in **fragment**

```
requestPermisions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE}
```

Don't use ActivityCompat.requestPermission because it should called from activity only not in fragment.