# How do you call from a fragment in a PageViewer?

Tags: android, permissions, fragment, call

I have a problem with my `Fragment` type in the `PageViewer`.

Normaly you need to check your permission but as you know the `PageViewer` only handles with `Fragmens` of type

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

Now if i want to call from this `Fragment`.what do i need to do in my `Activity` that is connected with my `Fragment`?

The normaly methode to override is the `onRequestPermissionsResult` methode but this methode doesn't excist in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check permission in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760625/how-to-check-permission-in-fragment)