# How to grant permissions for the Camera in Fragment

Tags: java, android

Hello I had simple application where I am using the camera, so the user must grant permission for the camera.

So far my app had only `Activity`, but now I want to use `Fragments`.
I got to fragments one is called `FragmentScanCode` (here I wanna use the camera ).

This is also the first fragment so I want to grant permission at the start of app.

There is my code from `MainActivity`, it works fine.

```
final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;
```

`onRequestPermissionsResult`:

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                RequestCameraPermissionID);

                        //return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

I can't use this in my `Fragment` because `ActivityCompat`.

Is any possible solution to grant permission on fragment?

This is what I tried based on developer.google.com doc and it works

**This is working code for me.**

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
                if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if(getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestPermissions(
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                RequestCameraPermissionID);
                        //cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                        return;
                    }
                }
                captureCode();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

and also in my function `captureCode()`

```
try {
                        if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            requestPermissions(
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    RequestCameraPermissionID);
                            return;
                        }
                        cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: might it will help you . https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#requestPermissions(java.lang.String[],%20int)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request runtime permissions from v4.Fragment and have callback go to Fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32890702/request-runtime-permissions-from-v4-fragment-and-have-callback-go-to-fragment)

Comment: Call `requestPermissions()` on the fragment and override `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in the same fragment.

Comment: @Ashish i tried do it with doc ( edited my question ) but still doesn't work.

Comment: @CommonsWare where should I call this method?

Comment: I can't answer that. You need to call it before you need the permission. So, for example, if this fragment is showing a camera preview, probably you should request permissions before you even try showing this fragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare works fine. I did it

Comment: @Ashish it works fine I did it based on documentation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be present in the v4 Fragment support class requestPermissions in Fragment. The Activity/FragmentCompat implementations exist for people who wish to use the native classes with the extended functionality on API levels between 11 and 23. [check this out](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#requestPermissions(java.lang.String[],%20int))