# Do I need runtime permission check to write into getExternalFilesDir() path in marshmallow?

Tags: android

In my android app, I save some files to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "\MyApp"` directory. This worked fine until android 6 marshmallow update. After marshmallow update, I cannot write to this directory.

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33164852/1015678) answer, in marshmallow, apps need to ask for the permission from user at runtime before writing to external storage.

But, when I use `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, I don't need to ask for any permission at runtime and it just works (path returned from `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` is also inside the external storage directory).

Is this some kind of a coincidence or can I continue to write to `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)` without asking permission at runtime?

Comment: Are you really able to write files to external storage without requesting permission on Android 6?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) states:

> Starting in KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to
>   the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This
>   only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling
>   application. To access paths belonging to other packages,
>   WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and/or READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are required.

You will have read/write access to `getExternalFilesDir()` on Android 4.4+ without requiring any permissions.

I would recommend using a [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) if you need to support lower API levels.

Comment: If I am targeting API 25, but supporting down to API 16, do I still need to declare the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the Manifest and then just not ask for the permission at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission
android:maxSdkVersion="18"
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

reference: [uses-permission-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element)

Comment: I have tested two device with Android 5.1. They are not working without permission, so change maxSdkVersion up to 22.

Answer (score 0):

As i know PERMISSIONS are presented started since Android 6 and above
So no need to check permissions for API 16