# Writing Access denied to removable SD Card

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, sd-card

I'm having a problem with writing to my external sd card. I'm getting a `UnauthorizedAccessException` whenever I try to write to it. I've already checked `WriteExternalStorage` in the Android Manifest.
Because `GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory`, `ExternalStorageDirectory` etc. are all returning the path to the internal storage, I'm using a manual path, `/storage/6363-3065/`. If I'm writing to my internal storage, the program runs without error, but it throws an Exception when writing to the sd card.
Can I do anything to solve this? I mean, it can't be impossible, because other programs like my file manager can do it without root or anything...

Edit:

I'm using a LG G4 with Android 6.0. Code is simple:

```
string filepath = "/storage/6363-3065/Temp/tempfile.temp";
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath));
```

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     string text="TestText";
     var dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString(), "yourAppName");
     if (Directory.Exists(dir) == false)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                }
       string dbFileSDCard = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString(), "yourAppName/YourFile.txt");
       System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@dbFileSDCard, text);
```

do you get errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors, but it doesn't solve my problem either because it just writes to the internal storage. As I wrote, the built-in functions are all returning paths to the internal storage, so I use a manual path to the sd card, but apparently don't have write access there.

Comment: have you found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card

Comment: It's not a problem with the permissions, they are checked and working. The problem probably lays somewhere in Android's way of handling sd cards and I'm searching for a xamarin way of solving this

Comment: in android 6 you can decide if you want to use your sd card as internal storage or external storage. look at this: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/109134/p/1449,9582  Which one did you select?

Comment: I can't between these two, the sd card is automatically portable storage

Comment: have you given your app permission: Settings > Apps > Specific App >  to write to sd card?