# How to test SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission granted when downloaded from Google Play Store

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, system-alert-window

According to this : [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW - How to get this permission automatically on Android 6.0 and targetSdkVersion 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an), the permission SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW is automatically given when the app is downloaded from the play store.

Is there a way to test this (without having to publish my app to the play store)?

It seems weird that you don't have to do any additional work considering that other less dangerous permissions require explicit granting.