# Floating view on android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to create a floating view ,I have android Marshmallow,I have found many guides on how to do this ,but every guide guides to add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

on android Marshmallow i need to ask for it at run time,my question is how apps like skype,facebook ,uses this feature without asking for this permission.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36019034/115145

Comment: so when i upload my app to the Play Store the permission will be give automatically ?

Comment: I would phrase it as: "when the user installs your app from the Play Store, if you requested `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`, it will be granted automatically". See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/24/system-alert-window-now-more-hidden-than-ever.html) for a bit more on this topic.