# Tooleap API does not work on Marshmallow?

Tags: tooleap

Tooleap API crashing on marshmallow device?what is the compatibility of this API?

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tooleap Api is compatible with Marshmallow devices. Without getting more details on the exact error you're getting I cannot help you, but your error might have something to do with the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission that requires a special treatment with Android 6.0.0 devices.
You can check out this post for more details:

[SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW - How to get this permission automatically on Android 6.0 and targetSdkVersion 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an)