# Covering window of UIAppDelegate with an overlay make user can't touch on extensions of UIActivityViewController when it's displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm creating an overlay which will cover all displaying views on screen. This overlay always appears even in case `rootViewController` changes, pushing or presenting.

**My idea is**

- Create `CustomWindow` which is a subclass of `UIWindow`. After that replacing default `window` of `UIApplication` with `CustomWindow`, create a new `rootViewController` for my new window.
- In `CustomWindow`, I have an `overlay` (is an `UIView`). `Overlay` have light gray color with an alpha and every event on `overlay` will be pass through to below view.
- Whenever `CustomWindow` add a new subview, i will bring `overlay` to front. It's make sure `overlay` will be on the top in every case.

**CustomWindow**

```
@implementation CustomWindow

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

  if (self) {
    _overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    _overlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _overlay.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self addSubview:_overlay];
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview {
  [super didAddSubview:subview];

  [self bringSubviewToFront:_overlay];
}

@end
```

Everything works fine in every case even when pushing, presenting or changing `rootViewController`.

**Problem**

But when i show an `UIActivityViewController`, I can't click on any extensions which are displayed on `UIActivityViewController`.

**Magically**

- When i click outside of `UIActivityViewController` or click on `Cancel Button`, `UIActivityViewController` is dismissed normally.
- If i change color of `overlay` to `clearColor`, it works fine too.

**My question is**

- How can i touch on extensions when i have `overlay` on window and `overlay` have a color ?
- If i can't, can anyone tell me why it happens ? It's perfect when you can quote the reason from a document.

I'm pretty sure this doesn't relate to how i initialize `UIActivityViewController` or the way i show `UIActivityViewController`.

**MORE**

I found a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174846/screen-overlay-detected-blocks-android-permissions/39247040#39247040) quite similar to this problem on `Android`. But i'm not sure because i haven't seen any official document about it from Apple. One more thing is when changing color to `clearColor` can affect touch. So actually, i don't think they are same.

Comment: I'm not on my mac to test your code but just got an idea. Did you try setOpaque method?

Comment: @ToughGuy Thanks for your suggestion but `setOpaque` doesn't help me in this case. Slowly, I can wait for another question from you when you can test my code.

Comment: I tried to make the Gray Box smaller in height making the buttons half visible. Basically touching any view other than ActivityViewController gives a responder event.

Comment: Try to Apply a Gesture and cancel touches so it doesn't receive any touch at all.

Comment: @ToughGuy did you try to click on `Cancel Button` or other things i wrote in **Magically**?

Comment: Yes. Maybe, the cancel button seems to be at application level layer. Just like an Alert Box. But it looks more like the cancel button is ignoring all other touches.

Comment: How about changing color of `overlay` to clear color? If you do it, you can click on everything. But window still has overlay on the top. I don't think color of view can affect touch

Comment: I am experiencing it for several years. Making it's opacity to 0 doesn't receive touches.

Comment: I tried to apply gesture on the custom view but it is not receiving any touches. I'm in a hurry right now. Good luck.

Comment: @ToughGuy thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a `UIRemoveView` (private) in the hierarchy. As best I can determine, your app cannot forward events directly to remote views. I suspect this is a security measure to prevent you from presenting the share dialog and automatically sending a touch event to it to do an external action the user didn't request. Remote views don't run in your application's process. The "Copy" button is interacted with across an XPC link.

This all means that if the remote view is covered by one of your views, there's no way (at least that I've found) to interact with it. You have to ensure that you're not covering it.

Actually doing that is simple. The thing that holds the remote view is called a `UITransitionView` and is used for other OS-level things that you probably shouldn't be covering either. So don't:

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview {
    [super didAddSubview:subview];

    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UITransitionView")]) {
        // To raise it above your overlay;
        // otherwise it's immediately above the view controller (below the overlay)
        [self bringSubviewToFront:subview];
    } else {
        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.overlay];
    }
}
```

But.... This requires you to talk about `UITransitionView` in your code. This is both fragile, and possibly a forbidden use of private APIs.

Otherwise you'll have to wrap your UIActivityViewController requests with some call/notification that tells the window not to cover views until we're done (which you'll have to clear in the completion handler).

Comment: As you said **if the remote view is covered by one of your views, there's no way (at least that I've found) to interact with it**, but when i change color of `overlay` to `clearColor`. I can touch extension items normally. Do you think we have something wrong here?

Comment: Since invisible views do not capture touch events, I suspect that the touch is being forwarded directly to the remote view rather than going through your view.

Comment: Totally agree. Seem like it's the answer i'm expecting. Once again thank you very much ;)