# How to customize Floating-ArcMenu (satellite menu option)

Tags: android, android-layout, floating

I want to implement arc-menu in my android app. I'm using [ArcMenu Lib](https://github.com/BrotherV/Floating-ArcMenu)
Here is [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJCSE.png) But I want Ui [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3I8X.jpg)
Is there anybody customize this library.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve it you have to get some permission and add use WindowManger to draw this overlay.

A detail explanation [**is here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174846/screen-overlay-detected-blocks-android-permissions)
An detail sample is [written here](http://%20https://github.com/henrychuangtw/Android-ChatHead)

Comment: This is not kind of assistive touch control. I want  floating arc-menu, you can check image which I attached

Comment: I can't code it for you first run that code and then simply use your custom arc instead of image view that floats on screen

Comment: this example for move image like fb messenger, I want bottom arc-menu to check attached images

Comment: remove touch listener from imageView and set your Arc Menu to bottom in WindowManager . There it work same as it does in simple layout screen

Comment: I don't how to use arc, I never used this. I just run this code https://github.com/BrotherV/Floating-ArcMenu :(

Comment: Do some code and ask question after putting some effort.