# Show app view on top of all other apps Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I have an app which enables users to set tasks with specific time deadlines. Once a deadline is passed, I want the app to show a view on top of everything (requesting the user to update the task).

My issues are:
- how to show my app's view on top of every other activity that is currently active
- how to keep the activity on top until the user updates the task?

Is using something like SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW look sensible?

Comment: These links might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355344/how-to-programmatically-grant-the-draw-over-other-apps-permission-in-android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an

Comment: How are you tracking deadlines in background ? AlarmManager ?

Comment: Use a heads-up notification instead

Comment: @ADM,  It's a service running in the background. Any code snippet for inspiration?

Answer (score 1):

You can try create a transparent Activity, open it and show alert dialog.

Comment: What if the app is in background?

Comment: The question is what's gonna call this Activity, yeah. Is it some kind of service of smth? In my case it's Push-notification and if user taps it the transparent activity with alertdialog appears.

Comment: In other words you have to move the app in foreground in order to do this.