# Android programmatically open the settings page for all the apps that controls draw over permission

Tags: android

I know there is a special settings page on Android devices that controls the appear on top permission. It is basically a page that have apps with a slider next to it that turns on/off appear on top permission.

For example on Samsung S10, you can find this page if you go to

Settings => Apps => ... => Special access => Appear on top.

And here is a screenshot.

[image]

Is there a way to open this settings page programatically ?

Comment: See [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355440/8043806)

Comment: Just to clarify, I don`t need this permission for my app so that post won`t help. The only thing I need is to open the settings page that I described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulled out from [android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/4feb4d9/src/com/android/settings/applications/DrawOverlayDetails.java)

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent mSettingsIntent = mSettingsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
                .setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
        try {
            startActivity(mSettingsIntent);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.w("ErrorLog", "Unable to launch app draw overlay settings " + mSettingsIntent, ex);
        }
    }
    else{
     //Device does not support app overlay
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to open the "special access" for "Wi-Fi control" (instead of appear on top)? Also see my separate SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531462/android-change-approval-status-permission-for-wi-fi-suggestion-api