# NoClassDeFounder Error

Tags: android

Getting error while running project with target v 22. I can not change target version.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

gradle file - build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adsl.beaconapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: `targetSdkVersion 26`

Comment: In that case it works ....but when I execute my code system ask for below permission :  Failed due to non declaration of following android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission in Manifest file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an

Comment: Yes I am doing the same steps but unfortunately it is not working....I have added the code to get runtime permission for SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW but still system throws same exception....

Comment: Its a permission issue  coming from API level 23 . You should proper add this .

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406719/3395198

Comment: Hi...implemented the code as per the shared link and permission granted successfully but still throwing same exception when my function executes..

Comment: add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />` in Manifest

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the build folder and then clean the project