# Add view error in Window

Tags: java, android

I have the following code

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
            localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | // this is to enable the notification to receive touch events
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN; // Draws over status bar

            localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            localLayoutParams.height = (int) (50 * getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
            localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;

            customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);

            manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

I add this in the `Android Manifest` : `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`

And i got this error: `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@1028c5e -- permission denied for window type 2010`

I test this in API 23 emulator. I know it's a permission problem, how can I handle it?

Comment: Starting from SDK 23 apps downloaded from PlayStore will have this permission automatically granted, and you need the user to enable the setting "Draw over other apps" manually

Comment: How can I achieve that? Could you give some explanation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36019034/2910520

Comment: I'll check thaht, thanks @MatPag