# How get permission apps that can appear on top

Tags: android, permissions, android-7.1-nougat

[How get this permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okeOh.jpg)

This just in nougat

Comment: what does that means that can can appear on top?

Comment: Select apps to allow their buttons, pop-ups, or other elements to appear over other apps you are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for this permission: [android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

Comment: Yes  but in nougat I have to take it from the user

Comment: Ok, I see...
[Check this answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406719/1720332)