# The SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission is not provided automatically after publishing to the Play Store

Tags: java, android, system-alert-window

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an), after publishing in Play Store for Android 6 device the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission has to be given automatically.

Here it's shown that my App has permission to draw over other apps.
[image: Description: App permission screen. Text: This app has access to: Other, Connect and disconnect from Wi-Fi, Full network access, draw over other apps]

But after downloading from Play Store it is not provided automatically.

[image: Description: App information screen. Text: Display over other apps, No]

I have announced `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` only in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

What else can I do to make users receive the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission automatically after downloading the app from an app store? Is there any chance that the Play Store will block me and not grant the ability to get the permission automatically?

Comment: Implement a permission check. Some devices won't have it automatically granted, even when installed from the Play Store. And some people just won't download it from the Play Store. You can't count on this behavior.

Comment: That post You quoted is already 2 years old, and auto-permission granting behavior was implemented for compatibility then.