# Dialog is not visible in Oreo even though I manually went to settings and allowed permission

Tags: android, dialog, type-application-overlay

I went to Permission Settings on my Phone & after **Display pop-up window - clicked checkbox**
Code:

```
private void showAlertDialog(final Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.myPasscodeAlertDialog)
                .setCancelable(false);

        View view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.row_passcode_dialog, null);
        passcode = view.findViewById(R.id.passcode);

        forgot = view.findViewById(R.id.forgot);
        setTextWatcher();
        setClickListener();
        builder.setView(view);


        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
                dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
        } else {
            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
        }
        dialog.show();


    }
```

I called above method from here & it is working fine for other version:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
        if (++activityReferences == 1 && !isActivityChangingConfigurations) {
            showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext());
            if (CREATE_PASSCODE_ACTIVITY == 0) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
```

It means there is no use of TYPE.APPLICATION.OVERLAY
What should I do? I tried everything. At least for testing purpose it should work on my Redmi Note 5 Pro 8.0.1

Comment: Hi, try changing compileSdkVersion to 26, buildToolsVersion to '26.0.2'

Comment: @Mr.Patel But, I want my app support to latest version.

Comment: can you try on some other phone? I think its MIUI problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an

Comment: @Gautam I tried other Oreo version phone also. It's not MIUI problem. Please help

Comment: @Quicklearner checked. no solution for Oreo, and in my phone, that option is available. Please help

Comment: please post code where you ask  ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION permission ?

Comment: @Quicklearner I didn't, first I'm testing on my phone. So I manually granted permission. Isn't it okay?

Comment: is it working in other versions of android or only in oreo it doesn't work?

Comment: TYPE.TOAST is working till nougat. Only oreo dosen't work.

Comment: First you need to ask user to enable permission , please add code

Comment: Why are you worried? I'll do it. First it should work in my phone.

Comment: @Quicklearner help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an implement the answe of this question

Comment: @Quicklearner I'm telling you again, that I do not need to separately download the patch file, because "draw over other app" option is built in Redmi Note 5 Pro. And I already grant my app.

Comment: how will you handle it on other devices ? you need to add permission code , request permission and show system alert, thats the right way my wear , you should understand it

Comment: @Quicklearner Send me code. I'll try it out. And I already used System Alert in manifest. Check it once again in my question please. And also check if/else condtion for below 27 or above devices.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an

Comment: @Quicklearner Yes I tried, but that is working till Nougat version. What about the Oreo? when that code open settings and I allowed it also, but dialog is still not showing. that code is to open Settings in phone. And I told you that I already allowed the permission also.

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing your if condition like this however i'm not sure if it will work or not:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
        } else {
            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
        }
        dialog.show(); 
   }
```

Comment: @PoojaSingh try providing runtime permission sometimes it solves the problem

Comment: @PoojaSingh No need to do any code for runtime permission just use this library
https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: If you're facing problems consuming the library tell me i'll help

Comment: I don't want to use any library. just help me for Oreo version.

Comment: This answer is not a solution. I test it Result:restarting of my App ! The main Q is Why android 9 does not support it ?