# Runtime permission for SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I need to get the user permissions automatically for the following permissions while user opens the app for the first time

1. Phone
2. Call logs
3. **Always on top**

Phone is working fine. How to get the always on top permission

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW}, 1);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: what does this code do?

Comment: expecting to ask the permission for always on top but it is not asking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there is no runtime permission/dialog for this purpose, you have to pass user to app settings

```
public boolean checkStartPermissionRequest() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            return false; // above will start new Activity with proper app setting
        }
    }
    return true; // on lower OS versions granted during apk installation
}
```

more info [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an)