# How to check, detect or identify the settings component screen overlay or any feature available or not

Tags: android, permissions, settings, overlay

My android app need display over other app permission which is screen overlay permission.

- Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION
- SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW

In normal android OS device i can give permission easily using this code.

```
if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this) && !Constant.IsOverlayPermissionGiven) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                handler.postDelayed(checkSettingOn, 200);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
```

But in Android Go edition device permission screen displaying the message of "This feature is not available" with the caution of "This feature has been turned off because it slows down your phone"

How to get the information about the feature is available or not programmatically ?
How to bypass the permission screen which device don't have screen overlay feature?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the Android 11 source code, you can see that it only uses `ActivityManager.isLowRamDevice()` to check whether the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` feature is available or not

**packages\apps\Settings\src\com\android\settings\Utils.java**

```
/**
 * Returns true if SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission is available.
 * Starting from Q, SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW is disabled on low ram phones.
 */
public static boolean isSystemAlertWindowEnabled(Context context) {
    // SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW is disabled on on low ram devices starting from Q
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return !(am.isLowRamDevice() && (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q));
}
```