# Clipboard returns null when I click on the button located in the top view activity and when MainActivity is not active

Tags: java, android, clipboard, system-alert-window

Clipboard data returns null when MainActivity is not active in top view activity when I click the button in Android java

I read this restriction about android10 and higher, but my activity is not a background service.
I need to get clipboard data when I click on the button located in the top view activity like the Google Translate application.
In my case, the clipboard returns null when MainActivity is not active.

[image: Google translate]
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data

```
public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initializes the Bridge
        this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
          // Additional plugins you've installed go here
          // Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);
        }});
        
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FloatingWindow.class));
    }
}



public class FloatingWindow extends Activity {
// ... additional code ....
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        floatingButtonDefinedInClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    self.getClipboardText(); 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void getClipboardText() throws IOException {
        try {
            ClipboardManager myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clipData = myClipboard.getPrimaryClip();
            if(clipData != null) {
                text = (String) clipData.getItemAt(0).getText();
                System.out.println(text); // returns null when mainactivity is not active 
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }    
// ... additional code ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what does "mainactivity is not active" mean? you are getting access to `ClipboardManager` inside `OnClickListener` attached to `Button`, which is a `View` and need `Context`, so there must be alive `Activity`, which keeps this `Button` on the screen for clicking purpose...

btw. maybe you are you checking on Android 10 or above? it looks like according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data)

> Limited access to clipboard data
>
> Unless your app is the default input method editor (IME) or is the app
> that currently has focus, your app cannot access clipboard data on
> Android 10 or higher.

privacy/security reasons, thats how it will be working now

Comment: Thank you for your reply @snachmsm, I meant when user switched to another application

Comment: is your code working on Android 9 and doesn't work on Android 10?

Comment: Yes, In android9 works perfectly, but in android10 not working

Comment: have you read linked docs? you can't do anything with this, it's safety feature. on iOS this is how it works since the beginning - only foreground window (`Activity` in Android ecosystem) can get access to clipboard

Comment: In that case how Google Translate works on Android 10?

Comment: first of all as I know Google Translate app you have to open it (is active) and then you may paste text there. another way - maybe `ForegroundService` can read clipboard and maybe Google Translate is using it (I doubt). last, but not least - Google apps oftenly have some additional necessary privileges as system apps or granted by system apps - Play store have huge possibilities and can share/grant some privileges/permissions during installation. e.g. check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an) topic