# How to place views on top of other views without using WindowManger?

Tags: android, sdk, system-alert-window

**Context:**

My android library requires to dynamically place views on on top of other target views. Currently I am using `WindowManager` for this purpose. I have the `viewId` of the target views and get the location coordinates of the views. Now I simply use `windowManager.addView()`. Issue faced here is that `WindowManager` requires `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission which we want to avoid.

I have also tried `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).addView(imageView)`, so that I donot have to use WindowManger but it is causing alignment issues for different phones.
Any help on how we could avoid using WindowManager and still fulfill our purpose at the same time?

**Alternative solution**:
I recently read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an) stackoverflow answer which said that permission won't be asked if installed from playstore. So I launched my app on playstore but it still asks for permission during runtime. I have also filled this [form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/adv_note).

**Edit:**

1. Using `ViewOverlay` as suggested by Mike. Issue is that drawables can only be added upto the region where associated `View` extends.
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eQSx.jpg)
2. Using `getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).addView(imageView)`
   Issue is that we get different alignment for different screens.
   [Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clGlK.png)
   [Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMyZJ.jpg)
3. Using `WindowManager`. Require `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission which we want to avoid.

Comment: What's your `minSdkVersion`? Starting with API level 18, every `View` has an overlay that you can add `Drawable`s in to be drawn on top of that `View`'s content. `ViewGroup`'s overlay also allows other `View`s to be added to it, so you could add your `View`s to the main content's overlay instead; e.g., `ViewGroup content = ...findViewById(android.R.id.content);`, `content.getOverlay().add(imageView);`. You'd have to manually position the `View`s yourself, IIRC, but it seems like you might already be mostly set up to do that, since you were figuring screen coordinates anyway.

Comment: @MikeM. minSdkVersion is 22. I have already tried adding `Drawable` to `ViewGroup` and manually set its coordinates, but there have been alignment issues for different phones. Can you elaborate on the overlay for `Views`?

Comment: I think I initially misunderstood what you mean by "alignment issues", and the overlay suggestion may end up giving you the same results, if I'm understanding correctly now. If so, then you might consider focusing on fixing those issues, because they will likely affect any solution that moves your `View`s from `WindowManager` into an `Activity`. Just a thought.

Comment: @MikeM. Please check edit

Comment: I tried to add `Drawable` over `android.R.id.content`'s overlay but I cannot see any change even after trying different bounds. Can you take at look at this? [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/gargVader/ViewOverlay/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/viewoverlay/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Here ya go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lq11refZ2Ekbwv6CwhJ2wLqbpLUi8QZq/view?usp=sharing. Hopefully that's a little more clear. I realize now that I tried to cram too much information into my first comment, and just confused things. My apologies. Anyhoo, here's a screenshot of what that quick demo should at least resemble: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBtJ7.jpg.

Comment: That was very nice of you. Can we do the same thing for `View`s too as was my original question? [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/gargVader/ViewOverlay/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/viewoverlay/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Yeah, but I forgot that they would have to be measured and laid out first, and since these `View`s are newly created on demand, we'll have to do it ourselves: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UrqcVEFHbKgSTAesUUphMCV4C85oAjcG/view?usp=sharing. Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRM6P.jpg.

Comment: Everything works well in your code except that `onClickListener` for the `View` doesnot work as expected. [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/gargVader/ViewOverlay/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/viewoverlay/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Mmm, no, overlay `View`s do not process touch events. It was not clear from the question that you're doing anything other than visual decoration with these.

Comment: Is there any other way that we can process touch events for the `View`s that are dynamically added on top of other `View`s? We are building an android library and if possible we would like to connect with you and discuss some queries regarding our product. Your expertise would definitely help us. [Chat Room](https://y99.in/rw/332135). My [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/in/girish23/)

Comment: Here's that example I mentioned earlier, if it's still needed: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZyrWUiZHs50_plfjITubd2KUhh5jrt3c/view?usp=sharing. The code's a bit different, and it now shows when clicking the `Button` instead of at startup, but it still uses the same layout. It results in exactly the same image as that from the last example.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. That works perfectly. I just set clickable to be false. I shall tag you again in some question if needed.

Comment: @MikeM. After adding the views, when I scroll the screen, the target views also move. But  the pointers that we have added donot move along with them as expected. Any approach that we could use to solve it?