# Can't create a directory on /storage/emulated/0 on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-external-storage

I'm trying to create a directory on my android emulator but I can't do it, I already have the permission on manifest write_storage, and I get no erros but mkdir() return false, I verify if external storage is writtable too and it is, it works on physical devices my code:

```
 /// Cria uma nova pasta para colocar o backup
    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "/Financas RW Backup");
    try {


        if (!direct.exists()) {
            if(isExternalStorageWritable()&&isExternalStorageReadable()) {
              if(  direct.mkdir()) {
                  fachada.showMessage(ExportImportDB.this," Criado");
              }else{
                  fachada.showMessage(ExportImportDB.this," Não Criado");
              }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fachada.showMessage(this, e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: use mkdirs(); it will create parent folders if its not there; but mkdir wont create and hence it will return false

Comment: I alreat try it, does not work

Comment: okay do this; Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), +"ur custom";

Comment: put your exception logs here.

Comment: are you running on Android 6?

Comment: @DJphy it does not work when I debug it the path is the same /storage/emulated/0/Financas RW Backup

Comment: @SilvansSolanki I have no exception

Comment: @g2o this is my config android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ".....financasrw"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

Comment: i hope you have permission in the manifest file for the SdCard.

Comment: check on another real time device; i think the phone ur checking has some problem; i gues :D

Comment: As I said it works perfect on phisical devices, and permission that I have is  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: If my help was valuable please don't forget to mark the question as solved ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to options:

- Downgrade your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to lower version in your `build.gradle`
- Request write permission at runtime is **required** on **Android 6**
  .

I personally don't advice the first one. For more info check:

- [Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Cannot write to SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card)
- [Google Play services 8.1 and Android 6.0 Permissions](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/09/google-play-services-81-and-android-60.html?m=1)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The problem is the version of android, and I tryed with a lower version and works!

Comment: Request permission works; we should get a warning in console about this.

Comment: Android Studio 3.1 and still no warning.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Android 10. I solved it by adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to my `<application>` element in the manifest

Note: We can also use `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`. There are other directory type constants in Environment like `DIRECTORY_MUSIC`, `DIRECTORY_MOVIES` etc.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue was fixed by using mkdirs instead of mkdir