# Android Studio with NDK-Build - Does not show C++ Files in Project Navigator

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, android-studio-2.3

I'm using Android Studio with NDK-Build and it does not show the single C++ files, so I can't debug. It only shows a cpp-Folder and insid ethe folder it shows some Static-Libraries, which I can not step in further. I remember that it was once possible to go inside these libraries (they opened like folders) and see the single cpp files.

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
    import java.util.regex.Pattern
    import com.android.build.OutputFile
    import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'



    task('increaseVersionCode') << {
        def buildFile = file("build.gradle")
        def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode\\s+(\\d+)")
        def manifestText = buildFile.getText()
        def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
        matcher.find()
        def versionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
        def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll("versionCode " + ++versionCode + "")
        buildFile.write(manifestContent)
    }

    // DO NOT change the build.gradle on debug builds any longer, since this will lead to debugging not work and Android Studio / Gradle crash
    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        if (task.name == 'generateReleaseBuildConfig' /*|| task.name == 'generateDebugBuildConfig'*/) {
            task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
        }
    }



    task deleteGraphicsAssets(type: Delete) {
        println 'Grade: Deleting unnecessary assets...'
        delete "assets/1136p"
        delete "assets/2048p"
    }
    preBuild.dependsOn deleteGraphicsAssets




    android {
        // Going higher means that we have to request to write to external storage (used for UUID): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084959/cant-create-a-directory-on-storage-emulated-0-on-emulator
        // But GameAnalytics reqires 24, let's see if it still works this way
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.3' // should be 25 for newer version
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.forestringgames.apps.towerduel"
            minSdkVersion 15
            // Going higher means that we have to request to write to external storage (used for UUID): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084959/cant-create-a-directory-on-storage-emulated-0-on-emulator
            // But GameAnalytics reqires 24, let's see if it still works this way
            targetSdkVersion PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
            versionCode 1602
            versionName "1.0"
    //        multiDexEnabled true

            externalNativeBuild {
                ndkBuild {
                    if (!project.hasProperty("PROP_NDK_MODE") || PROP_NDK_MODE.compareTo('none') != 0) {
                        // skip the NDK Build step if PROP_NDK_MODE is none
                        targets 'cocos2dcpp'
                        arguments 'NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9'
                        arguments 'APP_PLATFORM=android-' + PROP_TARGET_SDK_VERSION
    //                    arguments 'NDK_CCACHE='+System.getenv('NDK_CCACHE')

    //                    println 'A message which is logged at QUIET level:'+System.getenv('HOME')
    //                    println 'A message which is logged at QUIET level:'+System.getenv('NDK_CCACHE')
    //                    println "$System.env.HOME"


                        def module_paths = [project.file("../../FRGEngine/cocos2d").absolutePath,
                                            project.file("../../FRGEngine/cocos2d/cocos").absolutePath,
                                            project.file("../../FRGEngine/cocos2d/external").absolutePath]
                        if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                            // should use '/'
                            module_paths = module_paths.collect { it.replaceAll('\\\\', '/') }
                            arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(";")
                        } else {
                            arguments 'NDK_MODULE_PATH=' + module_paths.join(':')
                        }

                        arguments '-j' + Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
                        abiFilters.addAll(PROP_APP_ABI.split(':').collect { it as String })
                    }
                }
            }
            testApplicationId 'Test'
        }

        // only added for android debugging
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                if (!project.hasProperty("PROP_NDK_MODE") || PROP_NDK_MODE.compareTo('none') != 0) {
                    // skip the NDK Build step if PROP_NDK_MODE is none
                    path "jni/Android.mk"
                }
            }
        }

        sourceSets.main {
            java.srcDir "src"
            res.srcDir "res"
            jniLibs.srcDir "libs"
            manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
            assets.srcDir "assets"
        }
        splits {
            abi {
                enable true
                reset()
                include 'armeabi-v7a'
                //, 'armeabi',  'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'  - what about arm64? Test it with Crashlytics
                universalApk false  //true
            }

    //        density {
    //            enable true
    //            reset()
    //            include 'mdpi', 'hdpi', 'xhdpi', 'xxhdpi', 'xxxhdpi'
    //            compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
    //
    //        }
        }
        signingConfigs {

            release {
                if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                    storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                    storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                    keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                    keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                }
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false // Warning: is this a good idea?
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                if (project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                }

                externalNativeBuild {
                    ndkBuild {
                        arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=0'
                    }
                }
            }

            debug {
    //            debuggable true
    //            jniDebuggable true

                externalNativeBuild {
                    ndkBuild {
                        arguments 'NDK_DEBUG=1'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


crashlytics {
    enableNdk = true
    androidNdkOut = 'obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut = 'libs'

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    //    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':libcocos2dx')

    //    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    //    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
    // integration guide (with latest version numbers: https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle)
    // Crashlytics KitminifyEnabled
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    // NDK Kit
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
    //        transitive = true;
    //    }
    //
    //    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.2.0-SNAPSHOT:debug@aar') {
    //        transitive = true;
    //    }
    compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.7.3'
    compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:1.7.3'
    //    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
    compile files('Frameworks/Fmod/prebuilt/android/fmod.jar')
    //    // use latest version instead version number: https://github.com/GameAnalytics/GA-SDK-ANDROID
    //    compile 'com.gameanalytics.sdk:gameanalytics-android:3.5.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'Frameworks/Jars')
    //
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If I remove the following bit, the cpp-folder is gone - so it definitely does something...but not show the single files:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        if (!project.hasProperty("PROP_NDK_MODE") || PROP_NDK_MODE.compareTo('none') != 0) {
            // skip the NDK Build step if PROP_NDK_MODE is none
            path "jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's also the Android.mk:

```
$(info ANDROID.MK FILE PARSING)

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
CLASSES_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../Classes
PHOTON_SDK_ROOT := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../Frameworks/Photon


#
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#
#
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../FRGEngine/cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../FRGEngine/cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../FRGEngine/cocos2d/cocos)

#THE TRICK IS TO ACTUALLY NOT NAME FOLDERS TWICE - IF IMPORTING FRAMEWORKS HERE - THEN IMPORT /Fmod LATER - UNDER FRAMRWORKS
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../Frameworks)


LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp \
                gameanalytics/GameAnalyticsJNI.cpp \
                $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(CLASSES_PATH)/*.cpp)) \
                $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(CLASSES_PATH)/*.c)) \
                $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/libfixmath/*.c)) \
                $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/libfixmath/*.cpp)) \
                $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/ScreenLog/*.cpp)) \
                $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/PlayFabClientSDK/*.c)) \
                $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/PlayFabClientSDK/*.cpp)) \
                $(subst $(LOCAL_PATH)/,,$(wildcard $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/GameAnalytics/*.cpp)) 


LOCAL_CFLAGS += -fpermissive 

ifeq ($(DISTRIBUTION_TESTING),1)    
    $(info ADDING DISTRIBUTION TESTING PREPROCESSOR FLAG)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DDISTRIBUTION_TESTING=1
endif

ifeq ($(DISTRIBUTION_LIVE),1)   
    $(info ADDING DISTRIBUTION LIVE PREPROCESSOR FLAG)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DDISTRIBUTION_LIVE=1
endif


# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_BEGIN

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(CLASSES_PATH) \
                    $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/libfixmath \
                    $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/ConcurrentQueue \
                    $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/PlayFabClientSDK \
                    $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/ScreenLog \
                    $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform/GameAnalytics \
                    $(CLASSES_PATH)/../FrameworksCrossPlatform \
                    $(PHOTON_SDK_ROOT) \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/../Frameworks/Fmod/lowlevel/inc \
                    $(LOCAL_PATH)/gameanalytics

# _COCOS_HEADER_ANDROID_END


LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static loadbalancing-cpp-static-prebuilt photon-cpp-static-prebuilt common-cpp-static-prebuilt
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := fmod
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += fmodstudio

# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_BEGIN

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,.)




# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_BEGIN
# _COCOS_LIB_IMPORT_ANDROID_END


# PHOTON

$(call import-add-path,$(PHOTON_SDK_ROOT)/LoadBalancing-cpp/lib)
$(call import-module,loadbalancing-cpp-prebuilt)

# FMOD
#THE TRICK IS TO ACTUALLY NOT NAME FOLDERS TWICE - IF IMPORTING FRAMEWORKS HERE - THEN IMPORT /Fmod LATER - UNDER FRAMRWORKS
$(call import-module,Fmod/prebuilt/android)


# _COCOS_LIB_ANDROID_END
```

This is how it looks in Android Studio:
[image]

Comment: Same issue here and I can't find anything out other than use CMake but we cannot do that as we use a different project generation system

Comment: Actually just got this working, it turned out in the mode android studio runs the configure on it was inadvertently causing invalid options to be passed the makefiles meaning it didn't evaluate them properly.

Comment: In my case changing the cmake version helped me

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the NDK that was left blank in 
`Project Structure | SDK Location | Android NDK Location`
even if the NDK was installed with the SDK Manager.

After clicking the combobox and selecting the NDK, the `cpp` folder started to be populated with my native sources.

Answer (score 0):

ive been off a while, what happened to comments :)

anyway, according to this document you should have The cpp group folder under the java folder.

check here for instructions
[Add C and C++ Code to Your Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I actually believe I did everything in that guide. Check out the screenshot that I added now, so you can see how it looks for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem with a CMake project, the solution was that I had not added the .cpp files correctly to CMakeLists.txt

When I edited CMakeLists with an entry like this

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
         myNative-lib
         # Sets the library as a shared library.
         SHARED
         # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
         myCppFile.cpp )
```

then I could see myCppFile.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using for your gradle build tools?
I was previously using an older version until I changed it to 3.4.2 and I could see my files in the project hierarchy.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First download NDK ...

Go to File - Project structure and click on SDK location tab

[image]

Then move your path to C:// with full  project ( do no try to import only modules inside project )  ...

Import project again but from C://

If you dont have suceess try with other paths , try , try , try

You must try because problem  is that you must find correct path for your CmaleLists.txt ...
( example  # Set the path to the Oboe library directory
set (OBOE_DIR ../../../../..)  ......   etc ) ... But sometimes path is not path you see ...

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the problem of displaying the contents of cpp.
My issue was related to the CMake version.
After adding the line to local.properties

cmake.dir=C:\CMake\3.18.2

the structure of files and directories appeared.