# Cannot create directory and save picture taken by camera in storage/emulated/0

Tags: android, camera, storage, external

First and foremost, I'm testing this app using my Google Pixel XL (1st gen 32 GB version, runnning Android 9 API Level 28)

Basically, I'm trying to make a camera application based on Android Camera 2 API **(I just downloaded the sample code from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)**. and I'm stuck because I'm trying to save the picture taken by the camera into "Pictures" folder inside "`/storage/emulated/0/`".

However, for some reason even though it seems like I'm able to do this, the folder and the picture file are not there when I checked them with ES File Explorer.

I've tried 3 methods so far:

**Attempt #1:**

```
    mFile = new File(getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "newPicture.jpg");
    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())){

        mFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "picture.jpg");
        mFile.mkdirs();
    }
```

**Attempt #2:**

```
    File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),"randomFolder");
    if(!filePath.exists()){
        filePath.mkdirs();
    }
    String fullPathName = filePath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "newPicture.jpg";
    mFile = new File(fullPathName);
```

**Attempt #3:**

```
    mFile = new File(fullPathName);
    File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/");
    if (!filePath.exists()){
        filePath.mkdirs();
    }
    mFile = new File(filePath,"newPicture.jpg");
```

mFile is the File path where "newPicture" will be saved to, basically it's supposed to be saved to "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/newPicture.jpg"

Now, I've tried to use getExternalFilesDir() method so the picture will be saved into `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.***.***[the package name]/files/Pictures/newPicture.jpg`" and in this case, IT TOTALLY WORKS! However I REALLY want to save the picture to `/storage/emulated/0` directory because I want user to be able to access the data easily later on.

In order to illustrate this better, I've recorded the application running and then took a picture and saved it in a gif, uploaded it to imgur right here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNgH3.jpg

See that? The picture seems to be saved into "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/newPicture.jpg" successfully but then when I went to ES File Explorer to check the picture, the folder "Pictures" was not created, nada.

I'm literally on my wits end right here haha, does anyone know a solution to this problem? Any advice will be greatly appreciated

P.S. Almost forgot to say, I've already added the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: Did you allow external storage in AndroidManifest file?:


`<uses-permission
    
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: @guy Hi mate, thanks for the reply :) I DID yup, ooofff I forgot to say that in the post, I'll edit it right now.

Answer (score 2):

As someone said in this post:

[how-can-i-access-storage-emulated-0-dcim-on-android-device](https://superuser.com/questions/949659/how-can-i-access-storage-emulated-0-dcim-on-android-devic)
,
The "/storage/emulated/" folder does not really exist. It's what might be called a "symbolic link", or, in simpler terms, a reference to where the real data is stored. You'll need to find the actual physical location on your device where it is stored.

Maybe this link will help, Or this [Can't create a directory on /storage/emulated/0 on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084959/cant-create-a-directory-on-storage-emulated-0-on-emulator).

Comment: I don't know man..., it's a bit weird because if I try to use the "getExternalFilesDir()" method, it'll be saved into "`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.***.***[the package name]/files/Pictures/newPicture.jpg`" right? Well, the toast will show that it's saved there and when I check it with ES File explorer, "`newPicture.jpg`' was created there. Point is, I think the toast is showing the right thing, it's just not saved there for some reason.