# Android 6.0 Permissions Issues

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am having one heck of a time with this new permission request in Android 6. My app worked fine, and then in the last two days it is force closing all the time. If I change the target SDK level to 22, it works fine, but of course Play Store wont let you downgrade the SDK.

I need these permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

After this I am not sure how to work the requesting, or new way of implementing the permissions part so the errors will stop. I have been working on this for hours and have googled and search endlessly. While alot of examples out there all tell me to do the same thing, I just cannot seem to get it write in Android Studio. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is part of the code that was giving me issues.

```
public void exportSkin(View arg0) throws IOException {


    if (type.equals("popular")) {
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("skins/" + skinname + ".png");

        // create a File object for the parent directory
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath() + "/SkinYourself/");
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        //noinspection ResultOfMethodCallIgnored
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        // create a File object for the output file


        File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/SkinYourself/", "" + PopChar.character_name + ".png");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
        int read;

        while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        is.close();


    }
    if (type.equals("create")) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/SkinYourself");
        myDir.mkdirs();


        String fname = "SkinYourself" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 + ".png";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists()) file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /*sendBroadcast(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
    */
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "Your skin has been saved to the SkinYourself folder check the info button on how to use it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

    displayInterstitial();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } else {
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES))));
    }
}
```

Comment: "Here is part of the code that was giving me issues" -- please explain the issues. For example, if this code "is force closing all the time", use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If you do not understand the Java stack trace, edit your question and post it as part of explaining your issues.

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card

Comment: The READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE need permissions as they are considered dangerous. I am just not sure how to implement Android M new permission handling. If i Can just do it all at the start of the activity, or do I need to do it for every function that requests read or write permissions?

Comment: Yes, you can request all permissions at the start of the Activity. Be sure to check only if not yet granted

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful, and the code and examples provided work. I am just getting stuck on what part of my java activity I put the code. Anywhere I put it there seems to be a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Cannot write to SD Card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card)