# getExternalStorageDirectory does not save the files to SdCard

Tags: java, android, camera

the camera app that i'm writing has the permissions `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` both.

i use the `getExternalStorageDirectory()` method to write files to main directory of SD Card. I'm not running it on emulator. My device is `Xperia Z3C` and has `Android 6.0.1`.

when i have the path that `getExternalStorageDirectory()`'s given is `"/storage/emulated/0/".`

Then the files are saved on internal storage main directory.

```
 private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){



        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Flash");
        Log.d("adasd", mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath());



        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }


        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Comment: Are you checking runtime permissions like in the link : [android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card) and read [guides/permissions](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/permissions)

Comment: Yes. When it has installed first time, asks for all permissions that i've been declareted and gives the all.

Comment: "i use the getExternalStorageDirectory() method to write files to main directory of SD Card" -- [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on most Android devices. "Then the files are saved on internal storage main directory." -- no, they are not stored on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), at least in the way the Android SDK uses the term.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have already read it before asked here. but why i find them in the internal storage when i explore with one file explorer?

Comment: "why i find them in the internal storage when i explore with one file explorer?" -- this is covered in [the external storage blog post that I linked to](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). The terms that Google uses for ordinary users are different than the terms that Google uses in the Android SDK for app developers.