# Android 6.0 access sd card (download music)

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I tried [this link question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card) but don't run those ways.

I add part code relared to method "onClick", but it don't run.

In manifest added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="23" />
```

I don't understand what write in place of activity and parentActivity.

Comment: What is the problem? Post your problematic code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure runtime permission for giving support to Android 6.0 
Here is the url : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you are already tried this answer and still stucked, As you need to manage RuntimePermissions on API versions 23 and higher [**here**](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request) is documentation about adding permissions in android.

Although if you want to get all about RuntimePermissions simply i recommend you to follow [**this blog**](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en). It's a simple way to getting all about RuntimePermissions