# How to store file in Internal storage in android and access them from android phone

Tags: java, android, file, android-internal-storage

How to store files in Internal storage of android and how to access them in android phone. I googled a lot and found that we can store file but that can be accessed by only emulator or phone must be rooted.

What is solution for unrooted phones?

And how to access the internal storage files by giving its path? what will be the path?

Kindly help. Thanks in advance and examples will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't what you googled, but its an easy thing to do and to find. StackOverflow is not a "free coding service"

Comment: you want to store text file ?

Comment: @GaneshPatil any type of file

Comment: @MaximeLiege could you please share a link that would be helpful and successfully save files in internal storage of android and we can access them from android phone, because you said its easy... may be I am finding in wrong direction.

Comment: @Zobi, i really don't know how you could not find this : 

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by FileOutput stream:

```
    String fileName = "file.txt";
    String content = "hello world";

    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
       outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
       outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: This is the method to write into the internal storage only, MODE_PRIVATE means other apps can't access your file.
You also need to grant WRITE_EXTRENAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest xml.

This will store the file in: data/data/app/files/file.txt

To get a list of files saved in storage,

```
File dirFiles = mContext.getFilesDir();
for (String fname: dirFiles.list())
{
   Toast.makeText(mContext,fname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: It stores file in data/data/<com.mypackagename>/files.. How to I retrieve them, when I want to show them in listview ? and does it work for phones that are not rooted ?

Comment: dude, are you serious, with this sample code you can retrieve the file easily, StackOverflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: Check the edit, you can get a list of files stored, you can then show them in a listview. None of this requires a rooted phone

Comment: @ShubhamSinghal Thanks very much. It is successfully working on android emulator, but not working on android phone... Any Idea ?

Comment: On android versions above 6.0 you need to ask for write permissions. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139754/android-6-0-marshmallow-cannot-write-to-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

Just use a file explorer app. Most phones come with one pre-installed. If you don't have one, however, you can always download one of your choice. I use [ES File explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop).

From then it a matter of navigating to the file you want to access.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I want to make my own file explorer... for that purpose I want to save the files in internal storage of application and then retrieve to show that file.