# onRequestPermissionsResult() is never called in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, runtime-permissions

I'm trying to implement runtime permission, but there are few problems when `FragmentActivity` receive `onRequestPermissionResult()`. The `checkPermissions()` method works very well, but `onRequestPermissionResult()` is never called after User allowed or denied permissions.

When system dialog box shown to request permission, `MyActivity.onDestroy()` is never called. Is it relevant to this problem?

I've already tried to follow [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39298129/android-onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169455/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-dialog-fragment) , but I think I missed something.

My device is Nexus 5X (Android 6.0) and Target SDK version is 23.
Minimum support SDK version is 15.
Of course, I wrote required permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` and added v23 support libraries in build.gradle.

This is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkPermissions();
    }

    private void checkPermissions(){
        String[] dangerousPermissions = {
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
        };

        for(String permission : dangerousPermissions){
            if (!hasPermission(permission)) {
                Log.e("permission.debug", "need to grant " + permission);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, dangerousPermissions, 4);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean hasPermission(String permission){
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        Log.d("permission.debug", " request code " + requestCode);
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            if (grantResults[i] == 0 && Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.equals(permissions[i])) {
                initiate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is log for my code:

```
E/permission.debug: need to grant android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
E/permission.debug: need to grant android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
E/permission.debug: need to grant android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
E/permission.debug: need to grant android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please share your logcat ?

Comment: I tried to get some logs for this code, there were no errors or warnings.. It's weird.

Comment: You can find an answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714787/android-m-permissions-onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call requestPermissions directly rather than ActivityCompat.requestPermissions. Like below

```
if (checkNeededPermissions.size() > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Checking permissions");
    requestPermissions(this, dangerousPermissions, 4);
}
```

**EDIT**

I don't see where you have defined the list checkNeededPermissions. Could you please put a log inside as above

Comment: Unfortunately, minSdkVersion is `15`. so I must use `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions().`

Comment: @EugeneKim any reason why you are using FragmentActivity ?

Comment: @EugeneKim i have edited the answer above please check and try this once. And share your logcat

Comment: Sorry, I ommited details of the code. I edited my question and attached log for checking permissions.  @gaurav4sarma

Comment: @EugeneKim runtime permissions are applicable from sdK 23 only so why do you bother with your minSdkVersion 15 ?

Comment: Still `onRequestPermissionResult()` not being called when I changed FragmentActivity to AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I tried `AppCompatActivity.requestPermissions()`, but It has same problem with FragmentActivity.

Comment: Not AppCompatActivity just requestPermissions() like i have done in the answer above

Comment: I exactly did like that. It's just a expression of what class I used. (I know `AppCompatActivity.requestPermissions()` is not a static method.)

Answer (score 1):

I just found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35772265/2764443).

When you declare an activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` with `noHistory` attribute, It will remove your Activity task when Activity disappeared from screen.

To receive `onRequestPermissionResult()` callback, you must guarantee the Activity resumed.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Fixed it by calling **MyActivity.this** instead of **this** at the call to `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`