# onRequestPermissionsResult not getting called in signed apk, works fine in debug mode

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

In debug mode the app permissions work perfectly fine. When a signed apk is created with code obfuscation the onRequestPermissionsResult () is not getting called. Its done from Activity. Also targetSdkVersion is 23.

```
    public void requestStoragePermissions(){

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_STORAGE_ACCESS);

        }else{

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_STORAGE_ACCESS);

        }
    }
```

@Override

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_STORAGE_ACCESS:

        boolean result=PermissionUtil.verifyPermissions(grantResults);
        if(result){
            checkObbIsAlreadyDownloaded();
        }else{
            showPermissionAlert();
        }
        break;
    default:Log.d("APK", "from reader");

    }

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you have PERMISSIONS_STORAGE outside of the requestStoragePermission function

Comment: PERMISSION_STORAGE is nothing but an array of permissions that are requested. In this case read and write external storage

Comment: by the way where is your super.onRequestPermissionsResult

Comment: is this related your issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/35772265/6689101

Comment: Is super.onRequestpPermissionsResult valid here..  my activity just implemented the corresponding interface and amm using the method on the same activity..

Comment: tried removing the code obfuscation/proguard and its working fine in signed apk. Now looking for a way to resolve this in obfuscated apk