# I am unable to get longitude and latitude using FusedLocationProviderClient | Google Play services

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

I am trying to get the longitude and latitude but set it on a text view but idk why its not working i tried everything but i am not getting any results i am getting the permisiion dialog box but unable to show it

this is my main activity

```
package com.example.morror;



import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final static int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private TextView introTextView;
    FusedLocationProviderClient hello;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        hello= new FusedLocationProviderClient(SplashActivity.this);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        introTextView = findViewById(R.id.intro);

        getlastLocation();
    }

    private void letsgo() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent home=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(home);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }

    private void getlastLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            hello.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null){
                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        introTextView.setText("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    


}
```

I was trying to get the longitude and latitude using google play services

Comment: add your getlastLocation() function in callback after permission granted. btw did you add permission in manifest too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714787/android-m-permissions-onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called

Comment: yes i added it on my manifest

Comment: ok. then use callback to get data after permission granted