# permission maps & speed dial android 6

Tags: android

I'm build app with maps and speed dial for emergency call, min android 4.0 target android 6.0. At the time of testing at jellybean, kitkat, lollipops all the functionality works well but in marshmallow, maps and speed dial function does not work, maybe someone can help me to fix this problems?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask for Runtime permissions from Android 6.

See : 
1. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions

2. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html
3. [How to check Grants Permissions at Run-Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549561/how-to-check-grants-permissions-at-run-time)