# Marshmallow permissions should ask only if not already granted

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I'm developing an app that require multiple permissions, so i added it and did marshmallow code too, but the problem is when i re-open an app in marshmallow it always ask for permission, i want to ask only if its not granted.

kindly help me to code for it, Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Even if the permission is denied, you don't want to show it again?

Comment: if it denied then only it shows otherwise not @King

Comment: You can use Shared Preference to check that the permission are asked for first time.

Comment: @Pratik just need to put a check, if its already granted or not

Comment: @king do i need SharedPreference ?

Comment: No need of sharedpreference, as you want to show again, if permission not granted

Comment: as a king said just check ,if the permission is already allowed or not.if yes ,dont show the dialog again ,otherwise show it.

Comment: Interesting !!,Then how to do it @ing

Comment: @Pratik the main intension of android M runtime request to permissions is only to check if permission is granted or not. If not granted then only request for permission. As per your question I understood that you are not checking if granted or not and requesting everytime. Please check if permission is granted only they request if not requested.

Comment: do something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/30549756/1479511

Comment: Yeah i'm doing the same thing.. But still app is asking same permissions everytime when i open an app @King

Comment: add the code details too, plz

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for the permission and only request if neccessary.

Check permission with the help of

```
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
```

**Check if permission is already granted or not**

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant

    return;
}
```

**Then handle the permission**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission was granted, yay! do the

        } else {
            // permission denied, Disable the
            // functionality that depends on this permission.
        }
        return;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

the Permission system has changed. But here is a good explanation how to deal with it properly.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

This way the dialog is only opened once if the user grants permission. If he declines you have a option to show a explanation the next time the permission is requested.

They also have a section with best practices that is worth to read:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/best-practices.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public Boolean marshmallowPermission(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkPermission()) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            requestPermission();
            //marshmallowRequest();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean checkPermission(){

    int phone= checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
    if (phone == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void requestPermission(){

    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)){

        Toast.makeText(this," Permission must be needed which allows you to access an app. Please allow  in App Settings for additional functionality.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else {

        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},101);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 101:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Granted, Now you can access an app.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Denied, You cannot access call.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

- Create a group of permission you need to access.
- Pass the group/array to check permission granted or not

Sample code for your reference :

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String[]permissions) {
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

Above code will check your group of permissions later pass these all to ask for once

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1; 
//create all permissions array
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, //all your permissions};

//Now check whether permissions are granted or not
if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
}
```

Hope this will works out for you.