# Mac address for android 6.0 and above shows null

Tags: android, mac-address, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I am using this code to get MAC ADDRESS and display it in my app. The code works fine for all devices except most latest devices and ANDROID BOX.

it shows null for ANDROID BOX and other latest device.

Here is code:

```
   public static String getWifiMacAddress() {
    try {
        String interfaceName = "wlan0";
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            if (!intf.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(interfaceName)){
                continue;
            }

            byte[] mac = intf.getHardwareAddress();
            if (mac==null){
                return "";
            }

            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte aMac : mac) {
                buf.append(String.format("%02X:", aMac));
            }
            if (buf.length()>0) {
                buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length() - 1);
            }
            return buf.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";
}
```

I have written these permissions in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: @Have you given runtime permissions?

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { } // for now eat exceptions` "nice" exception handling **that's why you don't know what is really going on**

Comment: @KarthikCP which permissions?

Comment: I think we should have to give ACCESS_WIFI_STATE runtime permission. As in 6.0 and above, Adding permission in manifest alone will not help

Comment: ACCESS_WIFI_STATE is not dangerous permission ... so it is not true

Comment: @PirFahimShah have you referred the link i have posted in answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly u will check the permission is granted or not?

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
 String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Also, add below permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

[Please refer this link for 6.0 marshmalow](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id)

Comment: I have already done this code, but it does not show MAC ADDRESS for android 6 and ANDROID BOX

Comment: obviously it will not returns real mac on android 6.0 as is stated in the documentation ... it is not possible on android 6.0

Comment: U have forgot this permission

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @Selvin it is possible,refer the link i have posted in my answer

Comment: @AkshayTilekar i am getting 02:00:00:00 with the link code u prvided in your anwser

Comment: @PirFahimShah i have mentioned the cause in the answer !!

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to add Internet user permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

**and then Refer this to get mac address**: http://robinhenniges.com/en/android6-get-mac-address-programmatically

**And if it doesn't works then refer this**  [Android 6.0 changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id)
from this i have concluded that,

> To provide users with greater data protection, starting in this
>   release, Android removes programmatic access to the device’s local
>   hardware identifier for apps using the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth APIs. The
>   WifiInfo.getMacAddress() and the BluetoothAdapter.getAddress() methods
>   now return a constant value of 02:00:00:00:00:00.
>
> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via
>   Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the
>   ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions.
>   **Note** **That** : **you can't get your own MACs even having those permissions. Read carefully, It is said that you can get other devices MACs having those permissions, but not your own**.

Comment: i used the code in the link you provided me but it still not shows mac adress, it shows 02:00-00_00

Comment: @PirFahimShah i have edited the answer,have a look at that.

Answer (score -1):

As in 6.0 and above adding permission in Manifest alone wont work. You should have runtime permission and grant it if not granted.

Check this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30549756/3910281