# Web view click is crashing my app

Tags: android, webview

In my web view, I have this code. When I'm clicking a link in my web view application stops nd shows try again to open app.

```
myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String 
      contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {

        DownloadManager.Request request = new 
            DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookie = 
            cookieManager.getCookie("https://learntatatrusts.org/");
        request.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookie);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath(); 
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.
            VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.
            DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "download");
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) 
            getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        dm.enqueue(request);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: app has stopped..!!! this wil showing after clicking a pdf link in webview

Comment: I got that, but still you should get an error message on your Logcat. Look:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1Mko9TD8DI

Comment: ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
09-19 17:21:13.615 6023-6023/com.example.nisha.ttla E/chromium: [ERROR:interface_registry.cc(104)] Failed to locate a binder for interface: autofill::mojom::PasswordManagerDriver
09-19 17:21:24.702 6023-6023/com.example.nisha.ttla E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.nisha.ttla, PID: 6023

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Download/download: Neither user 10083 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
                                                                          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
                                                                          at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)

Comment: at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1276)
                                                                          at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:1014)
                                                                          at com.example.nisha.ttla.MainActivity$1.onDownloadStart(MainActivity.java:58)

Comment: (WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:1051)
                                                                          at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:162)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Comment: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit

Comment: .java:886)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: i'm glad that you found the error! did you know you can actually edit your question so you can add any missing info? next time it will be easier than posting on the comments below ;)

Comment: yes i wil do it next time..!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to ask for permission at runtime as well, no only in Android Manifest file. You can check it out here:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#explain

And here:

[How to check Grants Permissions at Run-Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549561/how-to-check-grants-permissions-at-run-time)

Answer (score 0):

```
Neither user 10083 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Have you tried to request the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your Manifest?

Comment: yes i did <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: @NishanthSingh on which  API you are working? If it's greater than 23 or 24 then need run time permission, read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)