# App won't run when apk is shared with friend

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My Android app is working fine on the emulator, and even on the device when I connect it using a USB cable. However, when I generate the apk file and share it with others, the app won't work. It crashes after the splash screen is launched.

Here is my app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.test'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"

        multiDexEnabled true

        def serverPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("server.properties")

        // Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
        def serverProperties = new Properties()

        // Load your keystore.properties file into the serverProperties object.
        serverProperties.load(new FileInputStream(serverPropertiesFile))


        buildConfigField("String", "HOST", serverProperties['SERVER_URL'])
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
} } dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Any help?

Comment: try disabling the instant run feature

Comment: May be permission issues. Above marshmallow, you have to request some permissions at runtime. Which os your friend's phone running?

Comment: I tried disabling too. But no use

Comment: @AswinPAshok May i know what are the permissions required?

Comment: can you provide crash log?

Comment: check manifest file for the permissions that your app require. What os your friend's phone running? Post your manifest file

Comment: @AswinPAshok Kindly check the posted manifest file

Comment: Most of your permissions are classified as dangerous permissions. So before doing any actions that involve those permissions you have to request for permissions.Have you done that in your code? (My English suck)

Comment: @AswinPAshok How can i check that?

Comment: Here is the link for the [list of dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous) and here is how you can [request permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). Without runtime permission request your app will work fine below marshmallow devices, but will crash on or above marshmallow.

Comment: @Jacky check my answer there is explaination and helpfull links

Comment: check out Tomin's links too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are lacking Runtime Permissions on API 23 or Above

Try giving Runtime permissions for **Camera, Location and Phone**. Here are examples of adding runtime permission.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

[How to check Grants Permissions at Run-Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549561/how-to-check-grants-permissions-at-run-time)

https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

To check if lacking runtime permission is the problem Go to Phone `Settings` -> `Apps` -> `Installed App` -> `Your App` -> `Permissions` -> `Allow Permissions` there

Comment: @Jacky Try adding runtime permission. To check if it is the problem Go to Phone setting -> Apps  -> Installed App -> Your App -> Permisisons -> Alow Permissions there

Comment: Permissions are allowed there.

Comment: If permissions are granted try opening app again

Comment: Deployment target is API 24. Is this making headache for me?

Comment: @Jacky possibly not.  The app won't be installed on a phone which has a higher API than 24. Try connecting the Phone to Android studio and have log.

Comment: @Jacky Are you generating a Signed APK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159276/discussion-between-tomin-b-and-jacky).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add some classes to your pro-guard file. Gson for example won't handle obfuscated very well. To see if this actually causes the problem, remove `minifyEnabled true`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to build and then click on generate/build apk. The apks generated by clicking on run are for devices with same API level.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the problem in APK version. check your mobile APK version and your targeted APK version. your App will not run Lower then APK version 25 as you built with 25.0.0

Comment: In case it is the problem app won't be Installed. So it is not the problem.