# How to get all permission in Marshmallow?

Tags: android, manifest, android-permissions

I am designing an app in android studio.i have included the all permission like `CAMERA` and `READCONTECTS` etc... in the AndroidManifest.xml file. It is working properly in all versions of android except Marshmallow. How do I set all permission by default?

Comment: Google for runtime permission. This question should be closed.

Comment: Ramesh Yogu,what you have tried so far to show multiple permissions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Grants Permissions at Run-Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549561/how-to-check-grants-permissions-at-run-time)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set permission on the java code also before it works

Example:

```
//declaration
private static final Integer CAMERA = 0x1;

//call this 
askForPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, CAMERA);

    /**
     *
     * @param permission
     * @param requestCode
     */
    private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {

                //This is called if user has denied the permission before
                //In this case I am just asking the permission again
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
            }
        } else {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[0]) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```