# Getting all the time "permission denied" or "no such file or directory" by trying to save Bitmap image. What should i do?

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, permission-denied

I`m trying to save Bitmap image by this code:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String filename = "test";
            File folder = new File(sdcard, "/Download");
            Log.v("ImageStorage1", "EXiST?: " + folder.exists());
            folder.mkdirs();
            Log.v("ImageStorage2", "EXIST!: " + folder.exists());
            Log.v("ImageStorage", "Folder: " + folder);
            File file = new File(folder, filename + ".jpg");

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I`m also using in manifests file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But i`m getting this one:

```
V/ImageStorage1: EXiST?: true
V/ImageStorage2: EXIST!: true
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.jpg (Permission denied)
    W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:287)
    W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:223)
    W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
```

Actually, my task is to store to another folder and when I`m using this:

```
File folder = new File(sdcard, "/kpi/test/a");
```

I`m getting

```
V/ImageStorage1: EXiST?: false
V/ImageStorage2: EXIST!: false
(No such file or directory)
```

Even with:

```
folder.mkdirs();
```

I tried a lot and surfed a lot, but haven`t found an answer :(

Comment: did you test it in real phone?

Comment: what is your target version?is it above 23? if so implement run time permisions

Comment: @ALTegani, yes, I`m trying it on real phone and emulator :(

Comment: @ALTegani, yes, its 26, dont know anything about runtime permission, so I`ll try to surf and do it

Comment: you should implement  runtime permisson  @Han vSolo

Comment: let me give you agood way for that ok?@Han vSolo

Comment: @ALTegani, You would be a hero for me, if u help me with this :D

Comment: yes just wait my post @Han vSolo

Comment: if ok with you mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) letting user to allow or deny any permission at runtime. use this lib [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) library.also check an working exmple [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-easy-runtime-permissions-with-dexter/)

Include the library in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
}
```

this example requests `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.`

```
Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                        // permission is granted, open the camera
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                        // check for permanent denial of permission
                        if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // navigate user to app settings
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).check();
```

Requesting Multiple Permissions
To request multiple permissions at the same time, you can use `withPermissions()` method. Below code requests `STORAGE` and `LOCATION` `permissions`.

```
Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            // do you work now
                        }

                        // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // permission is denied permenantly, navigate user to app settings
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                })
                .onSameThread()
                .check();
```

Comment: You are wellcome