# why shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale not work?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, permissions

how can use **shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale** before call permission and use in Activity.

because before ActivityCompat.requestPermissions this return false

```
if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(context,permission)){
    // true
}else{
    // false (always false)
}
```

Comment: use this for request permission its awesome  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49201404/9130109

Answer (score 3):

The method `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` returns true if it is required to explain the user why the permission is required. In the first time the permission is requested, this method returns **false**.

But if the user denies the permission once, when the permission is requested another time, this method returns **true** because it might be a good idea to explain the user why this permission is required for the app.

When the permission is already granted, this method will return **false**.

So a good practice would be to first check what this method returns and if it is required to explain to the user, explain it using a dialog or something followed by requesting the permission, otherwise ask the permission directly.

You can also have a look at my [library](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions) which ease up this whole process and other processes regarding run-time permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Addition info:
*Some case must use correct mapping permission requested and permission use to check shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale.*

In my case, I had used permission "granular media permissions" of Android 13 (READ_MEDIA_IMAGES/READ_MEDIA_AUDIO/READ_MEDIA_VIDEO) on device Android 10 and function **shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale** alway return **false**.

When i try use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, it' working and return true when use not have choose "Never ask again"

So let try old basicly permission before try another permission.

Good luck!