# Cannot resolve method askCompactPermission

Tags: java, android

I want to request permissions via spetial [library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5387#!description)

But when I'm trying to past this in my code I get this error.

[image: Look Please]

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        askCompactPermission(PermissionUtils.Manifest_CAMERA, new PermissionResult() {
            @Override
            public void permissionGranted() {
                //permission granted
                //replace with your action
            }

            @Override
            public void permissionDenied() {
                //permission denied
                //replace with your action
            }
            @Override
            public void permissionForeverDenied() {
                // user has check never ask again
                // you need to open setting manually
                openSettingsApp(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });


}}
```

Comment: use this lib descripe here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49212535/9130109

Comment: @ALTegani, thanks. U r the best!!!

Comment: you are wellcome ..if the answer fit you vote it up @Twikoffin

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you haven't followed the instructions till the end, as the guide you linked says your activity must extend "ActivityManagePermission", which defines the "askCompactPermission" method, and you're extending "AppCompatActivity", which explains the error you're seeing...