# Requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR or android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR

Tags: android, android-source, android-calendar, runtime-permissions

I've given READ_CALENDAR and WRITE_CALENDAR permissions in my Manifest and in my installed app I've given Calendar runtime permission and I verified the same from app's settings.

But even though, on some devices I'm getting **Requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR or android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR** error! This is insane! Here is my logcat:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2 from ProcessRecord{76fdbc0 21351:com.app.byday/u0a166} (pid=21351, uid=10166) requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR or android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1943)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1889)
       at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getContentProvider(IActivityManager.java:4885)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:6019)
       at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2525)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1791)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:749)
       at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:715)
       at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
       at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:54)
       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:315)
       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
       at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:64)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Additional info: I've integrated Etar-AOSP calendar app in my app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Grants Permissions at Run-Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30549561/how-to-check-grants-permissions-at-run-time)

Comment: I've given runtime permissions!

Answer (score 0):

Those require runtime permissions, not just manifest permissions on any modern version of Android.

Comment: I've given those permisson. As I verified from my app's setting too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add permissions to your manifest.xml For calendar, you need to add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
```

At runtime, you need to ask for permission again. So, you can create some functions to check it. Declare a vble for your callback

```
final int callbackId = 42;
```

and call to your function for checking permissions

```
checkPermission(callbackId, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

And this is the function to declare:

```
private void checkPermission(int callbackId, String... permissionsId) {
boolean permissions = true;
for (String p : permissionsId) {
    permissions = permissions && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, p) == PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

if (!permissions)
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsId, callbackId);
}
```